# Easily add an array of values in Javascript (eg. without loops)

Tags: javascript, arrays, optimization

I was wondering if anyone knows of a nice way of adding an array of values in javascript?

I came up with:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

var total = eval(myArray.join("+"));
```

Which is nice and short, but I'm guessing going from num to string and then evaling to get back to a number is a slow way of getting the total.

Comment: Yep I'd say that's definitely inefficient!

Comment: Why would you avoid loops? Much less use `eval` for this?

Comment: `eval` is evil. Didn't you get the memo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the sum of an array of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most appropriate method of doing this is to use the [`Array.prototype.reduce`](
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function, an addition to the language in ECMAScript 5th Edition:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5],
    total   =  myArray.reduce(function (curr, prev) { return curr + prev; });

alert(total);
```

Of course, this isn't supported in older browsers so you might want to include the [compatibility implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Compatibility) in your code.

Comment: Would this execute faster than `protoype.sum` function in my answer? This isn't a criticism btw I was not aware of the `reduce` function and it looks very useful but I would think that for something as simple as summing perhaps the `sum` would run faster?

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, I googled but didn't think to look on MDN.

Comment: @El Ronnoco: It would propably run slightly faster, but not even noticeable unless the array is really huge. What *really* bugs me about this solution is the verbose lambda needed for summing... operator sections are awesome (`sum = reduce (+)` anyone?).

Comment: @El: I would expect the native `reduce` to run faster, but not the compatibility implementation.

Comment: @delnan when you say 'it would run slightly faster' do you mean the `reduce` or the custom protoype?

Comment: @El Ronnoco: Your hand-rolled loop.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE - To combine Andy's method and the Prototyping method...

```
Array.prototype.sum = function(){
    return this.reduce(function(a,b) {return a+b} );
}
```

Now all array will have the `sum` method. eg `var total = myArray.sum();`.

Original answer...

I'd be tempted with just

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
var sum     = 0;

for (var i=0, iMax=myArray.length; i < iMax; i++){
    sum += myArray[i];
};

alert(sum);
```

break it out into a function if you're using it a lot. Or even neater, prototype it...

```
Array.prototype.sum = function(){
    for(var i=0, sum=0, max=this.length; i < max; sum += this[i++]);
    return sum;  
}

var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

alert(myArray.sum());
```

Courtesy of [DZone Snippets](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/769)

Comment: *Please* format properly. If the code seems to convulted, dropping formatting (in particular whitespace) is *not* an acceptable response.

Comment: @delnan I'm sorry, what exactly are you referring to?

Comment: @delnan - Do you mean the `for` loop formatting - if so, I have fixed it :)

Comment: @El Ronnoco: (Edit: Yes, although it could still be improved IMHO ;)) The loops. In about every sensible coding style, it would include two or three line breaks and spaces around operators.

Comment: @delnan I think the spaces round operators debate it ongoing :) Neither style offends my eye particularly.

Comment: I was tempted too, but I love all the tricks in javascript to perform operations with only a line or two.

Comment: Also it might be more efficient to implment with a while loop and pop() since then you are not updating i each iteration of the loop. Thanks for your suggestions :)

Comment: @David well the beauty of this trick is that once you've defined the protoype method you can call `.sum()` on any numeric array and there you go, 6 characters!