# Query through Json object

Tags: javascript

This is my JSON:

```
[{"Id":1,"Order":1,"IsDone":true,"Text":"abc","Date":"6/14/2014"},
 {"Id":2,"Order":2,"IsDone":false,"Text":"cde","Date":"6/15/2014"},
 {"Id":3,"Order":3,"IsDone":false,"Text":"fgh","Date":"6/16/2014"}]
```

What would be the most efficient way to get the count of IsDone == true?

Comment: You code doesn't look like JSON object, rather it's an array of objects. Also, this is very basic task in JavaScript, what have you tried?

Comment: The most efficient way is to use a for loop. here's the explanation => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550183/sum-of-values-in-an-array-using-jquery

Comment: LINQ.js will work also and from what I saw is pretty fast

Comment: I did do the loop approach. But just wondering if there are another way to tackle this. By the way thanks.

Comment: "most efficient" in what way? I doubt any of the posted answers will be faster than a regular `for` loop. Unless the data is sorted you will need to loop through all elements in the array.

Comment: 1. if the data is sorted, the counting process will be faster. 2. or you can return one more object (which is already count the data from the server), example: {totalDone:5}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use plain javascript iteration:

```
var a=[{"Id":1,"Order":1,"IsDone":true,"Text":"abc","Date":"6/14/2014"},{"Id":2,"Order":2,"IsDone":false,"Text":"cde","Date":"6/15/2014"},{"Id":3,"Order":3,"IsDone":false,"Text":"fgh","Date":"6/16/2014"}]

var ct=0;
a.forEach(function(entry) {
    if(entry.IsDone)ct++;
});
alert(ct);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use grep fron jquery

```
var selectedArray = [{"Id":1,"Order":1,"IsDone":true,"Text":"abc","Date":"6/14/2014"},
{"Id":2,"Order":2,"IsDone":false,"Text":"cde","Date":"6/15/2014"},
{"Id":3,"Order":3,"IsDone":false,"Text":"fgh","Date":"6/16/2014"}]



selectedArray = jQuery.grep(selectedArray, function (el) { return el.IsDone == true;   });

 alert(selectedArray.length);
```

where seletedArray is your actual array

http://jsfiddle.net/QxV6K/

Answer (score 0):

In case you're trying to access an item from the example structure by id or name, without knowing it's position in the array, the easiest way to do it would be to use underscore.js library:

```
    var data =   [{"Id":1,"Order":1,"IsDone":true,"Text":"abc","Date":"6/14/2014"},{"Id":2,"Order":2,"IsDone":false,"Text":"cde","Date":"6/15/2014"},{"Id":3,"Order":3,"IsDone":false,"Text":"fgh","Date":"6/16/2014"}];

    var allDesiredElements = _.filter(data, function(item) {
      return item.IsDone === true;
    });

//for length use
console.log(allDesiredElements.length);
```

Comment: `_.find` just finds the first one, not all of them.

Comment: I think you actually want `_.filter`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [{"Id":1,"Order":1,"IsDone":true,"Text":"abc","Date":"6/14/2014"},{"Id":2,"Order":2,"IsDone":false,"Text":"cde","Date":"6/15/2014"},{"Id":3,"Order":3,"IsDone":false,"Text":"fgh","Date":"6/16/2014"}];

var count = data.filter(function (el) {
  return (el.IsDone === true);
});

alert(count.length);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DianaNassar/jKRP6/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 var obj = [{"Id":1,"Order":1,"IsDone":true,"Text":"abc","Date":"6/14/2014"},
    {"Id":2,"Order":2,"IsDone":false,"Text":"cde","Date":"6/15/2014"},
    {"Id":3,"Order":3,"IsDone":false,"Text":"fgh","Date":"6/16/2014"}]

    var count = 0;
    for(i=0;i<obj.length;i--){
      count += (obj[i].IsDone) ? 1 : 0;
    }
```