# JSFiddle code not working in browser for sum calculation of row and column

Tags: html, jsfiddle

JSFiddle code not working in browser for sum calculation of row and column..please help me with code

the code is working in jsfiddle but not in my browser..if any addition of aother lines is necessary for work it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup HTML Editor (www.coffeecup.com)">
        <meta name="dcterms.created" content="Fri, 10 Apr 2015 05:07:13 GMT">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("table tr > td:nth-child(1) > input:not(#totalSum)").sum("keyup", "#totalSum");
    $("table tr > td:nth-child(2) > input:not(#totalSum1)").sum("keyup", "#totalSum1");
    $("table tr > td:nth-child(3) > input:not(#totalSum2)").sum("keyup", "#totalSum2")
    });
        </script>
        <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
      </head>
      <body>
      <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="1"   /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="2" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="3" /></td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="4"  /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="5"  /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="6" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="7" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="8" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="9" /></td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="totalSum" id="totalSum" value="" readonly="readonly" /></td>
             <td><input type="text" name="totalSum" id="totalSum1" value="" readonly="readonly" /></td>
             <td><input type="text" name="totalSum" id="totalSum2" value=""  readonly="readonly" /></td>
        </tr>    
    </table>


      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You are adding jquery twice. Remove one.

Comment: i tried it ,but still not working

Comment: You are missing a `"` after `id="5` in your table

Comment: where is the actual problem  when converting from jsfiddle to browser????

Comment: Could you please post the jsfiddle link showing the correct behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the script you're looking for: place it at the end of HTML code, just before `body` closure. (Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8550475/1219028) for the sum calculation). You can also refine it to calculate the sum only when data on column changes.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>

<script>
$("input:not(#totalSum)").keyup(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $("table tr > td:nth-child(1) > input:not(#totalSum)").each(function() { sum += parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0; }); $('#totalSum').val(sum); sum=0;
    $("table tr > td:nth-child(2) > input:not(#totalSum1)").each(function() { sum += parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0; }); $('#totalSum1').val(sum); sum=0;
    $("table tr > td:nth-child(3) > input:not(#totalSum2)").each(function() { sum += parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0; }); $('#totalSum2').val(sum);
});
</script>

<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```