# Sum array of numbers that resides in an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object called `fundsBeingSold`. This object contains an `Array[]` of numbers named `sliderValueArr`.

If this array has three values..

```
0: 59
1: 10
2: 12
```

how do I set a variable to be the sum of these values?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum of values in an array using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550183/sum-of-values-in-an-array-using-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the sum of an array of numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

```
var fundsBeingSold = {
    sliderValueArr: [59, 10, 12]
};

var sum = fundsBeingSold.sliderValueArr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
});

console.log(sum) // will print the sum 81
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
var total = fundsBeingSold.sliderValueArr.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use reduce:

```
var sum = fundsBeingSold.sliderValueArr.reduce(function(a,b){return a+b;},0);
```

You could also use JQuery for that:

```
$.each(fundsBeingSold.sliderValueArr,function(){sum+=parseFloat(this) || 0;});
```

---

If you want, you could also add a prototype to do it faster, like so:

```
Array.prototype.sum = function() {
  return this.reduce(function(a,b){return a+b;});
}
```

And you would use it like this: `var mySum = fundsBeingSold.sliderValueArr.sum();`

Answer (score -1):

you can do that operation using jQuery.map such as:

```
let arr = [ 59, 10, 12];
let result = 0;
jQuery.map(arr, function(str, i){
  return result += str
})
```

But you don't necessarily need jQuery you can do that with vanilla javascript using map as well, such as:

```
let arr = [ 59, 10, 12];
let result = 0;
arr.map(function(str) {
   result += str;
}
```

I hope that helps,

Bruno

Answer (score -1):

you can do :

```js
var fundsBeingSold = {
    sliderValueArr: [59, 30, 42]
};

var s = sum();

function sum() {
  s = 0;
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < fundsBeingSold.sliderValueArr.length ; i++) {
    s += fundsBeingSold.sliderValueArr[i];
  }
  s;
  return s;
}

console.log(s);
```