# I need to know if an array content is more than 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

HERE IS THE SUMMARY:

I prompt 3 value numbers for the array, if the addition total of the arrays elements are more than 0, i need to display "el funcionamiento no es infinito" otherwise "es infinito"

its not working due i think i am not calculating all element in the array danio_Total

HERE IS THE CODE, THANKS!

---

```
var comprobarTiempoFuncionamiento = function(i) {

    if (danio_Total.value > 0) {
        document.write("el funcionamiento no es infinito");
    } else {document.write("El tiempo de funcionamiento es infinito");}

}
```

Comment: what is `danio_total`

Comment: You need to sum the array as in [this SO answer][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1230238/2080716

Comment: danio_Total is the array where i have to evaluate the total addittion of all elements. for example if i have danio_Total [3,1,1] the result should be 5, and 5 is more than 0 so the log is "no es infinito"

Comment: I've added an answer, It should work

Comment: thanks Mritunjay, the other code below works! thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like bellow

```
 var total = danio_toal.reduce(function(a,b){
                 return a+b;
             });

 if (total > 0) {
    document.write("el funcionamiento no es infinito");
} else {document.write("El tiempo de funcionamiento es infinito");}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easier than it sounds, if you have an array and all you want to do is check if the sum is larger than zero, than you can reverse it and say that the sum would only be zero if all values in the array is zero (unless you have negative numbers), so this

```
[0,0,0,0]
```

would be the only type of array that would sum up to zero.

As zero's are falsy, you can just do

```
if ( danio_Total.filter(Boolean).length ) {
    document.write("el funcionamiento no es infinito");
} else {
    document.write("El tiempo de funcionamiento es infinito");
}
```

When filtering on Boolean, any positive integer will be truthy, so

```
[0,0,9].filter(Boolean).length; // returns 1, truthy
[0,3,9].filter(Boolean).length; // returns 2, truthy
[0,0,0].filter(Boolean).length; // returns 0, falsy
```

so it alls you really need.

Answer (score 0):

if you want know the length of array try this:

```
   for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    sum += array[i]; 
   }
```

Comment: doesn't give him what he wants, he needs to know the sum of the elements in the array, not just the count ;)