# I want a for that sum all the results of the 8 values of the array

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I want a `for` loop that sums all the results of the 8 values of the array

```
total=respuestas[1]+respuestas[2]+respuestas[3]+respuestas[4]+respuestas[5]+respuestas[6]+respuestas[7]+respuestas[8];
```

Comment: are you sure, that you have 8 values counting from `1`?

Comment: yes respuestas[1] can be 1 or 0 and I want sum all

Comment: what have you tried? you coould start by looking at the for loop syntax and examples on the web (hint: `for item in respuetas ...`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the sum of an array of numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is an iterated summation over the indices of the array.

```
var total =0;   
var i=0;
for( i=1; i<=8;i++){ 
    total += respuestas[i]; 
}
```

Another way to write the same thing, using the `forEach` loop.

```
var total = 0 ;
respuestas.forEach(function(entry){
    total += entry ;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```js
var sum = 0;
for (i in respuestas) {
  sum += respuestas[i];
}
```

sum contains your result. The for..in loop will count through all your objects properties (works for arrays as well as you can see). I think it looks cleaner than a normal for loop.

Comment: As a thumb rule, do not use the for loop with the in for an array. The for-in is intended for enumerable properties of an object, and bite the elements of an array.