# Sum of all elements in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I am a beginner in programming. I want to do the sum of all elements in an array. I made this but I can't see where are my mistakes?

```
function ArrayAdder(_array) {
    this.sum = 0;
    this.array = _array || [];
}

ArrayAdder.prototype.computeTotal = function () {
    this.sum = 0;
    this.array.forEach(function (value) {
        this.sum += value;
    });
    return this.sum;
};

var myArray = new ArrayAdder([1, 2, 3]);
console.log(myArray.computeTotal());
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`this` inside the `forEach` callback refers to the global `window` object. To set the context of the callback, use the [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) second argument to pass the context.

```
this.array.forEach(function (value) {
    this.sum += value;
}, this); // <-- `this` is bound to the `forEach` callback.
```

```js
function ArrayAdder(_array) {
    this.sum = 0;
    this.array = _array || [];
}

ArrayAdder.prototype.computeTotal = function () {
    this.sum = 0;
    this.array.forEach(function (value) {
        this.sum += value;
    }, this);
    return this.sum;
};

var myArray = new ArrayAdder([1, 2, 3]);

console.log(myArray.computeTotal());
document.write(myArray.computeTotal()); // For Demo purpose
```

---

If you're looking for an alternative, you can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), here using with [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
var sum = arr.reduce((x, y) => x + y);
```

```js
// Note: If this doesn't work in your browser,
// check in the latest version of Chrome/Firefox

var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var sum = arr.reduce((x, y) => x + y);

document.write(sum);
```

Comment: Using `reduce` is definitely more concise.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Reference of `this` got changed in `forEach` function. Update your code to following

```js
function ArrayAdder(_array) {
  this.sum = 0;
  this.array = _array || [];
}

ArrayAdder.prototype.computeTotal = function() {
  this.sum = 0;
  var that = this;
  this.array.forEach(function(value) {
    that.sum += value;
  });
  return this.sum;
};

var myArray = new ArrayAdder([1, 2, 3]);
console.log(myArray.computeTotal());
```

The above saved the reference of `this` in `that` and used it for computing.

Answer (score 1):

The most effective way of doing this is to use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) array function. For example:

```
this.array = [0, 1, 2, 3]
this.sum = this.array.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
});
```

Comment: ...as found in the question I've linked... This doesn't answer this question though.

Comment: Using reduce is definitely the most idiomatic way of solving this problem however. It might require some code rewriting on the asker's part, but it is definitely more effective.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
  let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  const sum = arr.reduce((x, y)=> x+y);
  console.log(sum);
```