# adding the first item from each dynamically created array together

Tags: javascript, arrays

Below is the structure of my data;

```
{
    "questions": ["Large choice of food", "Food quality", "Food freshness"],
    "countries": ["Netherlands", "Belgium", "France"],
    "values": [
        [
            [5, 88, 18],
            [50, 83, 10],
            [29, 78, 80]
        ],

        [
            [46, 51, 61],
            [95, 21, 15],
            [49, 86, 43]
        ],
        [
            [7, 46, 92],
            [54, 94, 31],
            [89, 96, 11]
        ]
    ]
}
```

Here is my script for sorting it;

```
 function calculateTotals() {
    var countryS = "France"
    var country = data.countries.indexOf(countryS);
    var values

  for (var question= 0; question < data.questions.length; question++) {
  // get the values for the question/country
  values = data.values[question][country];

  console.log(values)
```

Currently, this outputs this to the console;

[image]

So, currently this script is logging the values for each question indexed by country.

I would like to add together each item in this array. So, from this output I would like to do the following additions;

> 29 + 49 + 89,
>
> 78 + 86 + 96,
>
> 80 + 43 + 11

I'm not sure how I can do this?

I thought that perhaps using .pop()/.shift() 3 times might work, or just using [0],[1],[2]. However, after returning a single item in the array, I'm not sure how to add the 3 arrays numbers together?

Hope everything is clear, any help/advice is much appreciate!

[Plunk Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/n7RfJAHxbuEwFFYha2vJ?p=preview)

Comment: look into array.reduce()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an array for the sum amd iterate over the items as well.

Basically this proposal uses [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

> The **`forEach()`** method executes a provided function once per array element.

```js
function calculateTotals() {
    var countryS = "France",
        country = data.countries.indexOf(countryS),
        sum = [];

    data.values.forEach(function (question) {
        question[country].forEach(function (a, i) {
            sum[i] = (sum[i] || 0) + a;
        });
    });
    console.log(sum);
}

var data = { "questions": ["Large choice of food", "Food quality", "Food freshness"], "countries": ["Netherlands", "Belgium", "France"], "values": [[[5, 88, 18], [50, 83, 10], [29, 78, 80]], [[46, 51, 61], [95, 21, 15], [49, 86, 43]], [[7, 46, 92], [54, 94, 31], [89, 96, 11]]] };

calculateTotals();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to iterate over them and perform such an operation.

E.g.

```
var arr = [[29,49,89], [78,86,96], [80,43,11]];

var final = arr.map(function(v){
  var res = 0;
  v.forEach(function(e){
     res += e;
  });
  return res;
});

console.log(final); //[167, 260, 134]
```

For simpler, but not recommended, you can also achieve it by doing,

```
var arr = [[29,49,89], [78,86,96], [80,43,11]];

var final = arr.map(function(v){
    return eval(v.join('+'));
});

console.log(final); //[167, 260, 134]
```

Comment: @NinaScholz If he knwos what hes doing, why not :P.. or just ignore it and use the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

try the updated [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/CelixRXn4tiSeWznCCv2?p=preview)

Here is the updated method

```
  function calculateTotals() 
  {
    var countryS = "France"
    var country = data.countries.indexOf(countryS);
    var sum = [0,0,0];

    for (var question= 0; question < data.questions.length; question++) 
    {
      var values = data.values[question][country];
      for( var counter = 0; counter < values.length; counter++ )
      {
        sum[counter] += values[counter];
      }
    }
    document.body.innerHTML += sum;
  }
```

**DEMO**

```js
var data = {
  "questions": ["Large choice of food", "Food quality", "Food freshness"],
  "countries": ["Netherlands", "Belgium", "France"],
  "values": [
    [
      [5, 88, 18],
      [50, 83, 10],
      [29, 78, 80]
    ],

    [
      [46, 51, 61],
      [95, 21, 15],
      [49, 86, 43]
    ],
    [
      [7, 46, 92],
      [54, 94, 31],
      [89, 96, 11]
    ]
  ]
}

function calculateTotals() {
  var countryS = "France"
  var country = data.countries.indexOf(countryS);
  var sum = [0, 0, 0];

  for (var question = 0; question < data.questions.length; question++) {
    var values = data.values[question][country];
    for (var counter = 0; counter < values.length; counter++) {
      sum[counter] += values[counter];
    }
  }
  document.body.innerHTML += sum;
}

calculateTotals();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following with pure JavaScript with nested loops::
(If you want to get all the additions)

```
var arr = [[29,49,89], [78,86,96], [80,43,11]];
var resultArr;

for(var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    for(var j = 0, len2 = arr.length; j < len2; j++) {
        resultArr+= arr[j][i]; 
    } 
}
```

If you only want to get one sum at a time:

```
    var result;
    for(var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        result+= arr[j]["YourIndex"]; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array.reduce to achieve the desired output.

```
for (var question= 0; question < data.questions.length; question++) {
      // get the values for the organization/country
      values = data.values[question][country];

      console.log(values);

      var sumOfValues = values.reduce(
        function(previousVal, currentVal) { 
          return previousVal + currentVal; 
        }, 0);
      console.log("Sum of values");
      console.log(sumOfValues);
    }
```

here's the plunkr
https://plnkr.co//TckVhx52VcMGgb0eZjzW?p=preview

EDIT: 
array.reduce is one of the fastest methods available. Many links can be found for the info. 
I've got one here. See the answers. 
[How to find the sum of an array of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers)