# Making a function that adds numbers in an array and returns their sum in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function that will add the numbers in an array and return their sum. For some reason it's returning 1 instead of 15 and I'm not sure why.

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];  
function addThemUp(myArray) {
    var arrayTotal = myArray.length; 
    var totalSum = 0;

    for(var x = 0; x <arrayTotal; x++) {
        totalSum += myArray[x];
        return(totalSum)
    }
}

addThemUp(myArray)
```

Comment: You seem to be missing some code

Comment: oops sorry. Here is the missing code:

Comment: It's because your return is RIGHT in the for.  So, it runs once, and returns.  Boom.  done.  Move that return outside the FOR loop.

Comment: var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];  

function addThemUp (myArray) {

var arrayTotal = myArray.length; 
var totalSum = 0;

for(var x = 0; x <arrayTotal; x++){
    totalSum += myArray[x];
    return(totalSum)
}
}

addThemUp (myArray)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the sum of an array of numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers)

Comment: `myArray.reduce(function(a, b){ return a+b });`

Comment: return statement is the culprit here :)

Answer (score 4):

You placed the `return` statement inside the loop, so it will sum the first element only and then return. Instead, you should allow the loop to complete, and return the sum only after its done:

```
function addThemUp (myArray) {

    var arrayTotal = myArray.length; 
    var totalSum = 0;

    for(var x = 0; x < arrayTotal; x++){
        totalSum += myArray[x];
    }

    return(totalSum); // This is where the return should be
}
```

Comment: That definitely helped. That was my issue.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, you need to fix where the return of `totalSum` is, to be the last statement of your function (after the loop).

That being said, you may find that adding up all the numbers in an array is much cleaner and simpler to do with reduce:

```js
function addThemUp(myArray) {
  return myArray.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; });
}

var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(addThemUp(myArray));
```

Answer (score 2):

You should return sum after `for` loop

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function addThemUp(myArray) {

    var arrayTotal = myArray.length;
    var totalSum = 0;

    for (var x = 0; x < arrayTotal; x++) {
        totalSum += myArray[x];
    }
    return totalSum;
}

console.log("Sum of all elements: " + addThemUp(myArray));
```

Comment: Already been asked and has a much better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16751601/185672

Comment: I implemented the OP's code and changed the code to reflect your answer and it worked.

Comment: That was the problem. I had my return in the for loop. Thanks for the help