# Getting 180 Degree in a Triangle using Canvas Logic

Tags: javascript, css, math, canvas, logic

I am trying to create a small program where all degrees in a triangle will add up to 180 degrees. So far what I have is that when I use the Math.Random method, I get a random number but somethings the degrees do not add up to 180°. I have tried using the if condition statement but no luck so far.

Here is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/14p880p9/

```
    var a = Math.round((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    var b = Math.round((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    var c = Math.round((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

    var d = a + b + c;



    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(50, 10);
    ctx.lineTo(50, 450);
    ctx.lineTo(650, 400);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#666666';
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFCC00";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.font = "30px Comic Sans MS";
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillText(a + "°",52,60);


    //width distance, and then altitude
    ctx.font = "30px Comic Sans MS";
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillText(b+ "°",60,420);



    //width distance, and then altitude
    ctx.font = "30px Comic Sans MS";
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillText(c + "°",570,400);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**a) either use a stick...**

An easy way to tackle this is to visualize your `180` as a stick. You want to break that stick into 3 pieces. So all you need to do is generate two non-equal rounded random values from 1 to 179 (the cutting points: `one` & `two`). And your random values will be:

- `a`: from zero to smallest value cutting point
- `b`: from smallest to largest value cutting points
- `c`: from largest value cutting point to 180

```js
var Triangle = function() {
    this.getRandom = function() {
        // 1 - 179 random integer generator
        return Math.round(Math.random() * (179 - 1) + 1);
    }

    this.one = this.getRandom();
    this.two = this.getRandom();

    while (this.one == this.two) {
        // if equal, regenerate second - we don't want any segment to have 0 length
        this.two = this.getRandom();
    }

    return {
        'a': Math.min(this.one, this.two),
        'b': Math.max(this.one, this.two) - Math.min(this.one, this.two),
        'c': 180 - Math.max(this.one, this.two)
    }
}

// Now let's make a few tests... how about 180 tests?
for (var i = 0; i < 180; i++) {

    var t = new Triangle;

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = t.a + ' + ' + t.b + ' + ' + t.c + ' = ' +
        (t.a + t.b + t.c);

    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 33.3333%;
  float: left;
  padding: .5rem 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

---

**b) ... or maths**

While the above method is easy to visualize, and ensures each segment value has equal chances at being anywhere between `1` and `178` (`total` - (`parts` - 1 )),  it's not particularly efficient from a programming point of view.

Each time one of the cutting points overlaps an existing one, it needs to be recalculated. In our case that would be quite rare but, given variable values for `total` and `parts`, the odds of it happening might differ.
Besides, we can totally avoid having to regenerate any value, thus saving computing power and, ultimately, the planet, or at least delaying its doom by an insignificant amount of time.

If we look at this from a mathematical point of view, we'll notice

- at least `1` part will be smaller than `61` `((180 / (3 - 0)) + 1)`
- at least `2` parts will be smaller than `91` `((180 / (3 - 1)) + 1)`

So, as a general rule, at least `n` parts will be smaller than `(total / (parts - (n - 1)) + 1)`. Now let's rewrite our method, generating the minimal amount or random numbers, in the correct range of possible values.
We also need to add as a last value the difference between `total` and the sum of all previous values.
To make it more useful, I also considered `total` and `parts` as variables, so the method could be used to segment any `total` number into any number of `parts`.

```js
var Segmentation = function (total, parts) {
    this.random = function (min, max) {
        return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    }

    this.segments = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < parts - 1; i++) {
        this.segments.push(this.random(parts - i, total / parts + 1));
    }

    this.segments.push(total - this.segments.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0));
    return this.segments;

}
// let's test it

var h1 = document.createElement('h2');
h1.innerHTML = 'Triangles';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(h1);

for (var i = 0; i < 21; i++) {

    var t = new Segmentation(180, 3),
        div = document.createElement('div');

    div.innerHTML = '';
    for (var j = 0; j < t.length; j++) {
        div.innerHTML += t[j] + (t.length - j > 1 ? ' + ' : ' = ');
    }
    div.innerHTML += t.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
}

var h1 = document.createElement('h2');
h1.innerHTML = '<hr />Rectangles';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(h1);

for (var i = 0; i < 21; i++) {

    var t = new Segmentation(360, 4),
        div = document.createElement('div');

    div.innerHTML = '';
    for (var j = 0; j < t.length; j++) {
        div.innerHTML += t[j] + (t.length - j > 1 ? ' + ' : ' = ');
    }
    div.innerHTML += t.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
}

var h1 = document.createElement('h2');
h1.innerHTML = '<hr />Random segments';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(h1);

for (var i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
    var total = Math.round(Math.random() * (2000 - 200) + 200),
        parts = Math.round(Math.random() * (8 - 3) + 3),
        t = new Segmentation(total, parts);

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = ('full');
    div.innerHTML = '';
    for (var j = 0; j < t.length; j++) {
        div.innerHTML += t[j] + (t.length - j > 1 ? ' + ' : ' = ');
    }
    div.innerHTML += t.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 33.3333%;
  float: left;
  padding: .5rem 0;
  text-align: center;
}

div.full {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: initial;
}
```

Using this method, the first entry in the array has the biggest chances of having the smallest value while the last part has the biggest chances of having the highest value.

**Note:** Using this in a production environment is ***not*** recommended without sanitizing the input values.

**Another note:** To calculate the sum of all existing values in an array I used this [`awesome answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16751601/1891677)'s method.

Answer (score 3):

Use this, it can generate ANY combination, unlike the limited above option where one of the sides must be 1-100.

```
var a = Math.round((Math.random() * 90) + 1);
var b = Math.round((Math.random() * 90) + 1);
var c = 180 - a - b;
```

Comment: Theoretically, either `a` or `b` should be `Math.round((Math.random() * 60) + 1)`. Welcome to SO!

Comment: This is true, but still this method is shorter and less limited then the competing answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic for the generation of the randomness is a little off. At the minute you're asking it to generate 3 random numbers between 1-100. The downside to this approach is the numbers have no bearing on having to add to 180;

You should update this logic to know that the total must equal 180. Something like this:

```
var a = Math.round((Math.random() * 100) + 1); // generates a random number between 1-100
var b = Math.round((Math.random() * (179-a)) + 1); // generates a random number between 1-179 (minus a)
var c = 180 - a - b; // is the remaining value of 180 - a - b

var d = a + b + c;
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/14p880p9/2/)**

Comment: For some reason when I run your program, I received a negative degree. Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: So you always receive one? Or very rarely? I would imagine it would be extremely rare as i cannot replicate

Comment: In any case try changing line 2 to be 179-a instead of 180-a

Comment: Very rarely though. I would do that. Thanks