# Sum values from an Array, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Prompting the user for many inputs, storing it in an array, then printing summation , average, largest number, smallest number and bigger number than mean number.
I have defined a JavaScript variables called magicnumber which is a new Array , and print the value of array, like this:

```js
var magicnumber = [];

mymagicNumber();

function mymagicNumber() {
  //Specify the size of array
  var size = parseInt(prompt("How many data values do you need have?"));
  for (var i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
    //sorted in array
    var num = parseInt(magicnumber.push(prompt("Enter data value number " + i)));
    var s = magicnumber.join(', ');
  }
  //Display array element
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "Your data : " + s + "<br>";
}
```

```html
<div id="demo1"></div>
```

how I can summation it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the sum of an array of numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers)

Comment: In addition to the answers of the duplicate question, you should also learn how to do it in a simple `for` loop : initialise a sum variable at `0`, then for each element of the array, increase the sum by the element. At the end of the loop, the sum variable is equal to the sum of the elements of the array.

Comment: How I can print largest number and smallest number ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce) to get the sum

```js
var magicnumber = [];

mymagicNumber();

function mymagicNumber() {
  //Specify the size of array
  var size = parseInt(prompt("How many data values do you need have?"));
  for (var i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
    var promptValue = prompt("Enter data value number " + i);
    magicnumber.push(+promptValue);
  }
  var sum = magicnumber.reduce((a,b)=>{return a+b},0);
  //Display array element
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "Your data : " + magicnumber.join(', ');
  document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = "The sum : " + sum;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo1"></div>
<div id="sum"></div>
```

Comment: That's great, Thanks

Comment: How I can print largest number and smallest number ?

Comment: You should ask another question. Your current question is about sum. It is solved

Comment: Ok , Sorry I'm new here

Comment: it's not allowed to me . "We ask that you wait 6 days before asking again

Comment: What you are asking is very trivial and is a duplicate. Please do some researches before posting

Comment: I do it now it's true, The code run. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 more ways to find the summation, without using for loop.

```js
var magicnumber = [];

function mymagicNumber() {
//Specify the size of array
var size = parseInt(prompt("How many data values do you need have?"));

for (var i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
 //sorted in array
 var num = magicnumber.push(parseInt(prompt("Enter data value number " + i)));
}

var data = magicnumber.join(', ');
var s1 = magicnumber.reduce(function(acc, val) {
 return acc + val;
});

var s2 = eval(magicnumber.join("+"));


//Display array element
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "Your data : " + data + "<br>";
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Sum is: " + s1 + "<br>";
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = "Sum is: " + eval(s2) + "<br>";
}

mymagicNumber();
```

```html
<div id="demo1"></div>
<div id="demo2"></div>
<div id="demo3"></div>
```

Comment: That's great, Thanks

Comment: I have updated my code. I won't say it is the easiest but definitely another way of finding summation.

Comment: Your code snippet is not working anymore + You are combining `eval` and `reduce`... why ?