# Get the total of numbers in jsonobjectArray angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I'm I really don't know how to add all the numbers when I get the jsonObjectArray I'm using _.map in lodash and angular for each for getting the data in jsonObjectArray

```
$scope.dataNumbers = _.map(result.numbers);
  angular.forEach($scope.dataNumbers, function(value, key) {
  console.log(value.allNumbers)
})
```

When I console this is the response (8.17, 32.01, 37.45).

I tried to add them like this `Number(value.allNumbers) + Number(value.allNumbers)` but the result is (16.34, 64.02 , 74.9)

Sorry for the basic question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the sum of an array of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save it to a `$scope` or a global js `var`

```
$scope.sumOfNum = 0;
$scope.dataNumbers = _.map(result.numbers);
  angular.forEach($scope.dataNumbers, function(value, key) {
  $scope.sumOfNum += Number(value.allNumbers);
  console.log(value.allNumbers);
  console.log($scope.sumOfNum);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `reduce` instead

```js
const result = {
    numbers: [8.17, 32.01 , 37.45]
};

const allNumbers = result.numbers.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    return acc + Number(curr);
}, 0);

console.log(allNumbers);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use reduce function in javascript ,

```
var total=$scope.dataNumbers.reduce(function(total,num){
 return total+num
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `angular.forEach` to loop the `result.numbers` and add them

```
var _total;
angular.forEach(result.numbers, function(value) {
  _total += Number(value);
})
console.log(_total);
```

Or use `reduce`

```
$scope.total = result.numbers.reduce(function(total, curr) {
    return total + curr;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to calculate the sum of the numbers that are stored in the allNumbers field of $scope.dataNumbers, try

```
var sum = _.sum(_.map($scope.dataNumbers, 'allNumbers'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Usual way to sum the json object array values

```
var totalNumbers = 0;
angular.forEach($scope.dataNumbers, function(value, key) {
  totalNumbers += parseInt(value);
});
console.log(totalNumbers);
```