# Sum in 2-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have a matrix :

```
matrix = [[0, 1, 1, 2],
          [0, 5, 0, 0],
          [2, 0, 3, 3]]
```

I need to calculate Sum of all array elements which are not under 0
 So, in this example Sum should be  = 9

I have this function:

```
function matrixElementsSum(matrix) {
  // Write your code here
 var Summa =0
  for (i = 0; i<4; i++){
      var sum =0;
    // console.log(matrix[i].length); //4
    for(j=0; j<matrix.length; j++){
      console.log("Matrix JI "+ matrix[j][i])
         sum = sum +matrix[j][i]; 
         if (matrix[j][i-1]!=0){
           console.log(matrix[j][i-1])
           Summa =Summa+ sum;
         }
    }
    console.log('-----------' +Summa)
    console.log("Sum "+sum);
  }

  return Summa;
}
```

i think i need to change  `if (matrix[j-1][i]!=0)` but it doesn't work

Comment: I believe you can get started with this question and answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers  Perhaps then step through each one at a time?

Comment: @AaronBelchamber Nah. This is a question from CodeFights, not a generic  "how to sum an array".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` and inside `forEach()` loop for this. If the current element in  `foreach` loop is zero then you can store index of that element in one other object `zero` and you can use that object to check if there was zero with same index.

```js
var matrix = [
  [0, 1, 1, 2],
  [0, 5, 0, 0],
  [2, 0, 3, 3]
]

var zero = {}
var sum = matrix.reduce(function(r, e, i) {
  e.forEach(function(n, j) {
    if (n == 0) zero[j] = true;
    if (!zero[j]) r += n;
  })
  return r;
}, 0)

console.log(sum)
```

Comment: I'm a little confused on the mechanics here. I understand how reduce is adding the sum value, and how forEach is cycling through each individual array and filtering out the positive values. But how does forEach recognize the previous array had a zero in the same index spot?

Answer (score 1):

You can sum 2 arrays and ignore numbers from the bottom array, which items from the same index on the top array are 0.

Now you can iterate the matrix from the end, and sum the resulting array.

```js
const matrix = [[0, 1, 1, 2], [0, 5, 0, 0], [2, 0, 3, 3]];

const sumNotUnderZero = (bottom, top) => 
  top.map((v, i) => v ? v + bottom[i] : v);

const result = matrix.reduceRight(sumNotUnderZero)
  .reduce((s, n) => s + n);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) for building another array with valued column sums and then use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for a single number.

```js
var matrix = [[0, 1, 1, 2], [0, 5, 0, 0], [2, 0, 3, 3]],
    result = matrix.reduceRight(function (a, b) {
        return b.map(function (c, i) {
            return c && c + a[i];
        });
    }).reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to simplify it and use this:

```
function matrixElementsSum(matrix) {
    var Summa =0
    for (i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
      for(j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++)
         if (matrix[i-1][j] != 0)
           Summa = Summa + matrix[i][j];

    return Summa;
}
```

You need to access first the array above your current one, hence the `matrix[i-1]` and then the same column, hence the `[j]` in `(matrix[i-1])[j] ~ matrix[i-1][j]`