# Javascript - Sum solution

Tags: javascript

I am getting below line in my source file and I would like to `sum` those values separated by `pipe ("|")`

There is no limit for the values coming in the line (`might be 100 values`)

```
10|20|30|40|[no limit for values] - Separator is pipe "|"
```

The ouptput would be `100`

Please help to write a `javascript` function for the above query.

Regards
Jay

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow isn't just a code writing service, you need to show you have attempted something and indicate specifically where you are stuck.

Comment: Use `string.split()` to split the string into an array. Use `parseInt()` to convert those strings into numbers. And use `array.reduce()` to add them up.

Comment: close duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1230233/104380

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at JavaScript's built-in functions: With [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) you can split your string into an array, with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) you can 'reduce' your array to a single value, in that case via summation. These two links should provide you enough information for building your code.

Comment: Please don't encourage people who post poor questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `something` like below:

```
function sum(value){
  var total = 0;
  var array = value.split(",").map(Number);
  for( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     total += array[i];
  }
  alert(total);
}
var value = "10|20|30|40".replace(/\|/g, ',');

console.log(sum(value));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f7uqw7cL/