# Angular 4 - Sum of Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

new to ng4/typescript and having some difficulty. How do I sum the items in an array?

Added[image] screenshot of what it looks like in action for example

```
        for (let card of this.cards) {
              for (let val of card.cards){
                if(val.value == "JACK"){
                  val.value = 10;
                }
                if (val.value == "QUEEN"){
                  val.value = 10;
                }
                if (val.value == "KING"){
                  val.value = 10;
                }
                if (val.value == "ACE"){
                  val.value = 10;
                }

                this.hand = Number(val.value) + Number(val.value); (I'm sure this is wrong)

             }
          }
```

Comment: Start by a simpler task. Try summing the elements of the following array: [1, 2, 3, 4].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the sum of an array of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [Array#Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b):

```js
// Array of numbers
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
var sum = array.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0);
console.log(sum)

// Array of strings
var toNumber = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
var sumNumber = toNumber.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + Number(cur), 0)
console.log(sumNumber);
```

Comment: That's the thing, I tried this before I posted the question. toNumber doesn't work, it's just Number() in angular 4. Additionally, Number can't be called with reduce. That's the dilemma

Comment: @ChrisSimmons use than `parseFloat` or `parseInt` insted Number.

Comment: @ChrisSimmons If this solution works for you, mark answer as correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
let sum = array.reduce(function (acc, cur) { return acc + cur; });
```

Comment: Whilst this answer may be correct, some explanation of why and how would go a long way.

Comment: the array.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0); not work on AnularJS old versions, this that i have wrote works for all versions