# There is a blank array and i need add numbers

Tags: javascript

I have a blank array and i need to add the numbers from 1 to 20 to this array.
After that i need to sum these number totally. I am stucked in here:

```
for(i=1;i<=20;i++){
    push()
}
```

What do you think, please answer.
Thank you

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ah, do my homework!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/create-a-javascript-array-containing-1-n

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see... First you need to define an array like so:

```
var array =[];
```

And you also need to make a variable for the sum:

```
var sum = 0;
```

Now you use that for loop to add your numbers to the array:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
{
    array[i] = i;
    sum += i;
}
```

Hopefully this is what you were looking for.

Comment: From OP: *i need to sum these number totally.*

Comment: Yeah, forgot to add that. Updated my answer accordingly!

Comment: arrays are zero based. what happens to index zero?

Comment: Guess I typed `var i = 1` instead of 0. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly, this should help :

```
var i = 1,
    sum = 0,
    numbers = [];
// Filling the array :
for(i=1; i<=20; i++){
    numbers.push(i);
}
// Calculating the sum :
numbers.forEach(function(number) {
    sum += number;
});
```

And to see the result :

```
alert(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah you can achieve it simply just by making a push() function to the array variable like:

```
<script>
  function helloWorld(){
   var arr = Array();
   var sum = 0;
   for(var i=0;i<20;i++){
     arr.push(i+1);
     sum = sum+(i+1);    
   }
   console.log(arr,sum);
  }
</script>
```

in the console.log you will get the result

Answer (score 0):

another way to do it is with the use of `reduce`

```
  var arr = [];
      for(i=1;i<=20;i++){  //a for loop to create the array
        arr.push(i)
    }
    console.log("the value of the array is " + arr)
    var sum = arr.reduce(add, 0);
    function add(a, b) { // a function the calculate the total
        return a + b;
    }
    console.log("the total is " + sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative using the function `Array.from` to initialize and the function `reduce` to sum the whole set of numbers.

```js
var numbers = Array.from({length: 20 }, () => ( this.i = ((this.i || 0) + 1 )) ); //0,1,2,3.... and so on!
    sum = numbers.reduce((a, n) => a + n, 0);
    
console.log(sum);
```