# How come the returned value becomes undefined in my recursive function?

Tags: javascript

I wrote this sum function to get used to writing recursive function.

I thought it would work when I finish writing but the final summed value becomes undefined.

There is no async part in this function but the returned value of this function becomes undefined, which I don't understand why...

What am I doing wrong?

Could anyone please tell me how to fix this problem?

Thanks!!

## My code

```
function sum() {

    var numbers = [...arguments];

    if (numbers.length === 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (numbers.length === 1) {

        // it shows 15 here!!
        console.log(numbers[0]) 

        // But it returns undefined... Why!?
        return numbers[0]; 

    }

    var summedValue = numbers[0] + numbers[1];
    var restNumbers = numbers.slice(2);

    sum(summedValue, ...restNumbers)

}


console.log(sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) //undefined
```

Comment: As an alternative, you can use `function sum(...nums) {
  return nums.reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0);
}`

Comment: yeah! it's way shorter that way ;)

Comment: why use `apply`? you could use the spread syntax `...`, because you use ES6 with `Array.from`.

Comment: For more shorter ways, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers

Comment: @Nina Scholz spread syntax does not work in my editor somehow althouth Array.from do. I use code runner when writing a small script for fun and use web storm for a serious thing.

Comment: @Nina Scholz oh no my mistake. what I can't use in my editor is rest parameters and destructuring not spread operator.

I changed it. sum(summedValue, ...restNumbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return numbers[0];` doesn't return `undefined`, it returns correct value (**15** in your case).

However, your recursive function doesn't return anything to the `console.log`, make it

```
return sum.apply(null, [summedValue].concat(restNumbers))
```

**Demo**

```js
function sum() {

  var numbers = Array.from(arguments);

  if (numbers.length === 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  if (numbers.length === 1) {

    // it shows 15 here!!
    console.log(numbers)

    // But it returns undefined... Why!?
    return numbers[0];

  }

  var summedValue = numbers[0] + numbers[1];
  var restNumbers = numbers.slice(2);

  return sum.apply(null, [summedValue].concat(restNumbers))

}


console.log(sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) //undefined
```

Comment: oh...!!!! ok... Thank you so much for spotting this. I could not find it by my self without help.