# Count combine product from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have a array like this:

```
const arr = [2, 3, 4, 12, 4, 55, 8, 16]
```

I want to get the sum of every five element of array's product.
My current way is use five times for loop to calculate the result.
It's holy shit!
Is't have a elegant way to solve it?

The output should same as the below method:

```
 function getSum(arr) {
  let sum = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 4; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length - 3; j++) {
      for (let k = j + 1; k < arr.length - 2; k++) {
        for (let l = k + 1; l < arr.length - 1; l++) {
          for (let m = l + 1; m < arr.length; m++) {
            sum += arr[i] * arr[j] * arr[k] * arr[l] * arr[m]
         }
      }
    }
  }
 }
  return sum
}
```

Possible tuples for the above given example:

```
2 3 4 12 4
2 3 4 12 55
2 3 4 12 8
2 3 4 12 16
2 3 4 4 55
2 3 4 4 8
2 3 4 4 16
2 3 4 55 8
2 3 4 55 16
2 3 4 8 16
2 3 12 4 55
2 3 12 4 8
2 3 12 4 16
2 3 12 55 8
2 3 12 55 16
2 3 12 8 16
2 3 4 55 8
2 3 4 55 16
2 3 4 8 16
2 3 55 8 16
2 4 12 4 55
2 4 12 4 8
2 4 12 4 16
2 4 12 55 8
2 4 12 55 16
2 4 12 8 16
2 4 4 55 8
2 4 4 55 16
2 4 4 8 16
2 4 55 8 16
2 12 4 55 8
2 12 4 55 16
2 12 4 8 16
2 12 55 8 16
2 4 55 8 16
3 4 12 4 55
3 4 12 4 8
3 4 12 4 16
3 4 12 55 8
3 4 12 55 16
3 4 12 8 16
3 4 4 55 8
3 4 4 55 16
3 4 4 8 16
3 4 55 8 16
3 12 4 55 8
3 12 4 55 16
3 12 4 8 16
3 12 55 8 16
3 4 55 8 16
4 12 4 55 8
4 12 4 55 16
4 12 4 8 16
4 12 55 8 16
4 4 55 8 16
12 4 55 8 16
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: *My current way*.. and where is it ?

Comment: can you please explain  "every five element of array's product"?

Comment: I think the accepted answer to this question would work for you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers

Comment: The output should same as my current solution@Vineesh

Comment: It's not@MiquelAdell

Comment: Sorry about my English grammar, Maybe you can figure out what I mean by my current solution code@N.Jadhav

Comment: I just add my current solution@DontVoteMeDown

Comment: please add how many tupels do you get and the sum.

Comment: The sum should be 2927456  @NinaScholz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach by checking the wanted length and by calling the function again with ither the element at the index or without.

```js
function getCombinations(list, size) {

    function fork(index, values) {
        if (values.length === size) {
            result.push(values);
            return;
        }
        if (index >= list.length) {
            return;
        }
        fork(index + 1, values.concat(list[index]));
        fork(index + 1, values);
    }

    var result = [];
    fork(0, []);
    return result;
}

var result = getCombinations([2, 3, 4, 12, 4, 55, 8, 16], 5),
    sum = result.reduce((s, a) => s + a.reduce((a, b) => a * b), 0);

console.log(sum);                          // 2927456
console.log(result.length);                //      56
console.log(result.map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```