# How do I format the sql value "[a,b,c]"?

Tags: php, html, sql, json, formatting

On a game, there are three different teams. For example, team a, b, and c.
On the game's database the playtime is reported like this: "[a,b,c]" and each letter is how many minutes the user has played on that specific team.
I used PHP to grab the data from the database to display on a website, but it is just displaying as "[14,0,1]" as I have 14 minutes on team a, 0 on team b, and 1 on team c.

How can I format this, through PHP or JSON, to add a, b, and c, or in this case 14+0+1?

The code in PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM players WHERE playerid ='". $steamprofile['steamid']  
."'";
$result = $db->query($sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $playtime = $row["playtime"];
    }
```

The code in HTML:

```
<span id="label">Playtime</span>: <b><span id="playerPlaytime"><?php echo 
$playtime; ?></span></b><br>
```

Output:
http://prntscr.com/jum85v

Comment: What does PHP think playtime is?  var_dump(playtime).  If your PHP is modern enough that actually matches the new array notation ... hmm ;-)

Comment: So you want `15` as the result???

Comment: string(9) ""[14,0,1]""

Comment: yes, I want 15 as the result but if I played 6 more minutes and it was "[20,0,1]" it would say 21

Comment: If you want JSON/JavaScript instead, the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 1):

Create an array by splitting on commas and then calculate the sum (trim extra stuff first):

```
$playtime = array_sum(explode(',', trim($row['playtime'], '"[]')));
```

To use JSON you still need to trim the quotes:

```
$playtime = array_sum(json_decode(trim($row['playtime'], '"')));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the variable from the DB is a string (it appears to be, perhaps, a JSON object), then in PHP you could do this:

```
$playtime = array_sum(json_decode($row['playtime']));
```

Comment: If you want to do it in JSON, go here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers