# How to get sum of pushed array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function

Can someone help me to get sum of pushed numbers to array ? I need to get sum displayed after 20th Rounds. I push scorePoint which is typed by player and all the score need to be multiplied after 20 round to see result.

```js
var round = 1;
var score1 = [];

function roundNr() {
  round++;
  document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = round;
}

function scoreCntr() {
  var scorePoint1 = document.getElementById('score1').value;
  score1.push(scorePoint1);

  if (round > 20) {
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="input_box">
  <input type="name" placeholder="Name" id="name1">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Score" id="score1">
  <button onclick="roundNr(); scoreCntr();">Submit</button>
</div>

<div class="round_box">
  <h1>ROUND</h1>
  <p id="p">1</p>
</div>

<div id="score">

</div>
```

Comment: You have an array of strings, not numbers, but otherwise: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers

Comment: `score1.push(+scorePoint1); ...innerHTML = score1.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);`

Comment: Thank you so much ! I am student at javascript, so i didnt know about it. But anyways thanks for info.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `score1.forEach(val=>sum+=parseInt(val));` inside the `if` condition that will calculate the sum. Also note that when you push the value it is string type so you need to use `parseInt()` to get the integer value before adding them.

```js
var round = 1;
var score1 = [];

function roundNr() {
  round++;
  document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = round;
}

function scoreCntr() {
  var scorePoint1 = document.getElementById('score1').value;
  score1.push(scorePoint1);

  if (round > 20) {
    var sum = 0;
    score1.forEach(val=>sum+=parseInt(val));
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = sum;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="input_box">
  <input type="name" placeholder="Name" id="name1">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Score" id="score1">
  <button onclick="roundNr(); scoreCntr();">Submit</button>
</div>

<div class="round_box">
  <h1>ROUND</h1>
  <p id="p">1</p>
</div>

<div id="score">

</div>
```