# How to access the changed value of an onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner in javascript and am doing an MMA score, I would like to know how I could access the changed value of result1Red.

```
<span><a id="result1Red">0</a></span>
```

which is changed by choosing one of the buttons that activates its respective function:

```
function tenRed1() {
  var i = 10;
  result1Red += 1*i;
  if (result1Red > 10) {return;}
  document.getElementById("result1Red").innerHTML = result1Red;
};

function nineRed1() {
  var i = 9;
  result1Red += 1*i;
  if (result1Red > 10) {return;}
  document.getElementById("result1Red").innerHTML = result1Red;
};

function eightRed1() {
  var i = 8;
  result1Red += 1*i;
  if (result1Red > 10) {return;}
  document.getElementById("result1Red").innerHTML = result1Red;
};
```

When I try with "innerHTML" it returns 0 (the initial value) 
and not the determined value. I need this value to add up with the other inputs and get the total result.

Complete code:

```js
// Round 1
function tenRed1() {
  var i = 10;
  result1Red += 1*i;
  if (result1Red > 10) {return;}
  document.getElementById("result1Red").innerHTML = result1Red;
};

function nineRed1() {
  var i = 9;
  result1Red += 1*i;
  if (result1Red > 10) {return;}
  document.getElementById("result1Red").innerHTML = result1Red;
};

function eightRed1() {
  var i = 8;
  result1Red += 1*i;
  if (result1Red > 10) {return;}
  document.getElementById("result1Red").innerHTML = result1Red;
};

function tenBlue1() {
  var i = 10;
  result1Blue += 1*i;
  if (result1Blue > 10) {return;}
  document.getElementById("result1Blue").innerHTML = result1Blue;
};

function nineBlue1() {
  var i = 9;
  result1Blue += 1*i;
  if (result1Blue > 10) {return;}
  document.getElementById("result1Blue").innerHTML = result1Blue;
};

function eightBlue1() {
  var i = 8;
  result1Blue += 1*i;
  if (result1Blue > 10) {return;}
  document.getElementById("result1Blue").innerHTML = result1Blue;
}


// Round 2
function tenRed2() {
  var i = 10;
  result2Red += 1*i;
  if (result2Red > 10) {return;}
  document.getElementById("result2Red").innerHTML = result2Red;
};

function nineRed2() {
  var i = 9;
  result2Red += 1*i;
  if (result2Red > 10) {return;}
  document.getElementById("result2Red").innerHTML = result2Red;
};

function eightRed2() {
  var i = 8;
  result2Red += 1*i;
  if (result2Red > 10) {return;}
  document.getElementById("result2Red").innerHTML = result2Red;
};

function tenBlue2() {
  var i = 10;
  result2Blue += 1*i;
  if (result2Blue > 10) {return;}
  document.getElementById("result2Blue").innerHTML = result2Blue;
};

function nineBlue2() {
  var i = 9;
  result2Blue += 1*i;
  if (result2Blue > 10) {return;}
  document.getElementById("result2Blue").innerHTML = result2Blue;
};

function eightBlue2() {
  var i = 8;
  result2Blue += 1*i;
  if (result2Blue > 10) {return;}
  document.getElementById("result2Blue").innerHTML = result2Blue;
};


// Round 3
function tenRed3() {
  var i = 10;
  result3Red += 1*i;
  if (result3Red > 10) {return;}
  document.getElementById("result3Red").innerHTML = result3Red;
};

function nineRed3() {
  var i = 9;
  result3Red += 1*i;
  if (result3Red > 10) {return;}
  document.getElementById("result3Red").innerHTML = result3Red;
};

function eightRed3() {
  var i = 8;
  result3Red += 1*i;
  if (result3Red > 10) {return;}
  document.getElementById("result3Red").innerHTML = result3Red;
};

function tenBlue3() {
  var i = 10;
  result3Blue += 1*i;
  if (result3Blue > 10) {return;}
  document.getElementById("result3Blue").innerHTML = result3Blue;
};

function nineBlue3() {
  var i = 9;
  result3Blue += 1*i;
  if (result3Blue > 10) {return;}
  document.getElementById("result3Blue").innerHTML = result3Blue;
};

function eightBlue3() {
  var i = 8;
  result3Blue += 1*i;
  if (result3Blue>  10) {return;}
  document.getElementById("result3Blue").innerHTML = result3Blue;
};
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>MMAScore Beta</title>
 <link rel="styleesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<header>
 <h1>mmaScore 0.1 Version</h1>
</header>

<!-- Round 1 -->
<div class="roundOne">
 <button type="button" onclick="eightRed1()">8</button>
 <button type="button" onclick="nineRed1()">9</button>
 <button type="button" onclick="tenRed1()">10</button>
 <span><a id="result1Red">0</a></span> - 
 <span><a id="result1Blue">0</a></span>
 <button type="button" onclick="tenBlue1()">10</button>
 <button type="button" onclick="nineBlue1()">9</button>
 <button type="button" onclick="eightBlue1()">8</button>
</div>
<!-- Round 2 -->
<div class="roundTwo">
 <button type="button" onclick="eightRed2()">8</button>
 <button type="button" onclick="nineRed2()">9</button>
 <button type="button" onclick="tenRed2()">10</button>
 <span><a id="result2Red">0</a></span> - 
 <span><a id="result2Blue">0</a></span>
 <button type="button" onclick="tenBlue2()">10</button>
 <button type="button" onclick="nineBlue2()">9</button>
 <button type="button" onclick="eightBlue2()">8</button>
</div>
<!-- Round 3 -->
<div class="roundThree">
 <button type="button" onclick="eightRed3()">8</button>
 <button type="button" onclick="nineRed3()">9</button>
 <button type="button" onclick="tenRed3()">10</button>
 <span><a id="result3Red">0</a></span> - 
 <span><a id="result3Blue">0</a></span>
 <button type="button" onclick="tenBlue3()">10</button>
 <button type="button" onclick="nineBlue3()">9</button>
 <button type="button" onclick="eightBlue3()">8</button>
</div>



<h3>Total:</h3>
<span id="resultRed">0</span> - 
<span id="resultBlue">0</span>
<footer>
</footer>



<script type="text/javascript" src="script/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It should be `span` not `spam` :)

Comment: Where are you trying to access that value?

Comment: `result1Red += 1*i` ... but where is `result1Red` initialized?

Comment: what you'll need in each of those functions is `var result1Red = Number(document.getElementById("result1Red").innerHTML)` - before `result1Red +=` etc

Comment: I have added explanation along with my code. Enjoy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Regarding your code

First I would like to point a couple of issues with your code and give you some advice :

- write `<span>` instead of `<spam>`
- `<a>` tags are for links only you don't need to have `<span><a>...</a></span>`
- try to use less ìds and class names
- don't use [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) if you're not planning on adding HTML, use [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead
- your JavaScript code is way too redundant: you've defined 18 similar functions! Functions need to be reusable.

---

### A proposal

Here's how you could implement your process.

- we will add an event listener to the document to listen to any clicks inside the page. We'll use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for that.

  ```
  document.addEventListener('click', function() {})
  ```

  As you can see it takes the event type (`'click'`) and a callback function that it will execute when the event happens. We need to define this callback.
- The callback needs to first check that the clicked item is indeed a button and it's parent (if he has any) has the class name: `.round`.

  ```
  const parent = event.target.parentElement;
  if (parent && parent.classList.contains('round')) {
    ...
  }
  ```

  If the condition is met then it means the user has clicked on one of the buttons.
- In the if block we can start working with `event.target` which is the element that has been clicked (in our case it will be one of the `<button>` element). We will start by saving some variables: `button` (the `<button>` element), `amount` (the button's value) and `team` (the team: either `'Red'` or `'Blue'`).

  ```
  const button = event.target;
  const amount = button.textContent;
  const team = button.className.substr(3);
  ```
- Then we will update the round's point:

  ```
  parent.querySelector('.result'+team).textContent = amount;
  ```
- And finally, update the total amount using `updateTotals`:

  ```
  updateTotals('.result'+team);
  ```

---

**Full code:**

```js
const updateTotals = function(className) {
  const total = [...document.querySelectorAll('.round '+className)]
    .map(e=> parseInt(e.textContent))
    .reduce((a,b) => a+b);
  document.querySelector('.results > '+className).textContent = total;
};

document.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const parent = event.target.parentElement;
  if (parent && parent.classList.contains('round')) { // this is a <button>
  
    const button = event.target;
    const amount = button.textContent;
    const team = button.className.substr(3);
    
    // update team score
    parent.querySelector('.result'+team).textContent = amount;
    
    // update total for each team
    updateTotals('.result'+team);
    
  }
});
```

```html
<h1>mmaScore 0.1 Version</h1>

<!-- Round 1 -->
<div class="round round1">
  <button class="btnRed" type="button">8</button>
  <button class="btnRed" type="button">9</button>
  <button class="btnRed" type="button">10</button>
  <span class="resultRed">0</span> -
  <span class="resultBlue">0</span>
  <button class="btnBlue" type="button">10</button>
  <button class="btnBlue" type="button">9</button>
  <button class="btnBlue" type="button">8</button>
</div>

<!-- Round 2 -->
<div class="round round2">
  <button class="btnRed" type="button">8</button>
  <button class="btnRed" type="button">9</button>
  <button class="btnRed" type="button">10</button>
  <span class="resultRed">0</span> -
  <span class="resultBlue">0</span>
  <button class="btnBlue" type="button">10</button>
  <button class="btnBlue" type="button">9</button>
  <button class="btnBlue" type="button">8</button>
</div>

<!-- Round 3 -->
<div class="round round3">
  <button class="btnRed" type="button">8</button>
  <button class="btnRed" type="button">9</button>
  <button class="btnRed" type="button">10</button>
  <span class="resultRed">0</span> -
  <span class="resultBlue">0</span>
  <button class="btnBlue" type="button">10</button>
  <button class="btnBlue" type="button">9</button>
  <button class="btnBlue" type="button">8</button>
</div>

<h3>Total:</h3>
<div class="results">
  <span class="resultRed">0</span> -
  <span class="resultBlue">0</span>
</div>
```

---

**About `updateTotals`:**

The function allows to take the sum of all points for the specified team. It takes as argument `className` of type `String` which can either be `'resultRed'` or `'resultBlue'`.

Here's how it works:

1. it starts by selecting all of the point elements and spreading the selection returned by [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) into an array.

   ```
   [...document.querySelectorAll('.round '+className)]
   ```
2. then we can map this array like so HTMLElement => Number using [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

   ```
   .map(e=> parseInt(e.textContent))
   ```
3. then the resulting mapped array can be reduced to a single integer: the sum of all the elements of the array using a [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). Here's a Stack Overflow thread on [How to find the sum of an array of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers).
4. Finally change the team's total count in the DOM with the calculated sum `total`.

As a result we have:

```
const updateTotals = function(className) {
  const total = [...document.querySelectorAll('.round '+className)]
    .map(e=> parseInt(e.textContent))
    .reduce((a,b) => a+b);
  document.querySelector('.results > '+className).textContent = total;
};
```

Comment: first of all thanks for the JavaScript writing tips! quick response and very very helpful. I'll have enough to study for days with your answer.

Testing your suggestion I get this error:
{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Can not set property 'textContent' of null",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 71,
  "colno": 54
}
what could it be?

Comment: me? I'm sure I did not do that.

Comment: No, I don't know if it's you. It's someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Found post already has accepted answer and 4 upvotes when I finished this. I'm going to post it anyway, just for ref.

```js
NodeList.prototype.map=Array.prototype.map;

const sum=()=>{
 resultRed.innerText=document.querySelectorAll(".resultRed").map(x=>x.innerText).reduce((a,b)=>Number(a)+Number(b));
 resultBlue.innerText=document.querySelectorAll(".resultBlue").map(x=>x.innerText).reduce((a,b)=>Number(a)+Number(b));
}

for(const cn of document.querySelectorAll("body>div").map(x=>x.className)){
 const parent=document.getElementsByClassName(cn)[0];
 parent.querySelectorAll("button").forEach((v,i)=>{
  if(i<=2) v.onclick=()=>{
   parent.querySelector(".resultRed").innerText=v.innerText;
   sum();
  }
  else v.onclick=()=>{
   parent.querySelector(".resultBlue").innerText=v.innerText;
   sum();
  }
 });
}
```

```html
<!-- Round 1 -->
<div class="roundOne">
 <button type="button">8</button>
 <button type="button">9</button>
 <button type="button">10</button>
 <spam><a class="resultRed">0</a></spam> - 
 <spam><a class="resultBlue">0</a></spam>
 <button type="button">10</button>
 <button type="button">9</button>
 <button type="button">8</button>
</div>
<!-- Round 2 -->
<div class="roundTwo">
 <button type="button">8</button>
 <button type="button">9</button>
 <button type="button">10</button>
 <spam><a class="resultRed">0</a></spam> - 
 <spam><a class="resultBlue">0</a></spam>
 <button type="button">10</button>
 <button type="button">9</button>
 <button type="button">8</button>
</div>
<!-- Round 3 -->
<div class="roundThree">
 <button type="button">8</button>
 <button type="button">9</button>
 <button type="button">10</button>
 <spam><a class="resultRed">0</a></spam> - 
 <spam><a class="resultBlue">0</a></spam>
 <button type="button">10</button>
 <button type="button">9</button>
 <button type="button">8</button>
</div>



<h3>Total:</h3>
<spam id="resultRed">0</spam> - 
<spam id="resultBlue">0</spam>
<footer>
</footer>
```