# How to sum array values with an iterator without a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, iterator

I want to get the sum of the values of an array only using an iterator function. Below, I get the individual values using an iterator but I'm using a for-loop to ultimately summing their values.

Is there a more elegant way to accomplish the same result using only an iterator function?

```
function sumArray(arr) {
    function nextIterator() {
        let i = 0;
        var iteratorWithNext = {        
            next: function nextElement() {
                var element = arr[i];
                i++
                return element;
            }
        }
        return iteratorWithNext;
    }
    var iteratorWithNext = nextIterator();

    let sum = 0;
    for (item of arr) {
        sum = sum + iteratorWithNext.next();
    }
    return sum;
}

const array4 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(sumArray(array4)); // -> 10
```

Comment: `let sum = 0; for (let val of arr) sum += val; return sum;` - `for ... of` works on iterables, maybe i don't understand what you want, but it sounds like it already does exactly what you want. E.g. `let iterable = (function*() { yield 1; yield 2; yield 3; })(); for (let val of iterable) console.log(val);` works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the sum of an array of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers)

Comment: What do you mean by "*using an iterator function*" if not the builtin iterator feature, and why do you want to use that instead of simply iterating the array like everyone else?

Comment: Iterators are used because they can yield multiple values, which makes certainly no sense with only one value

Comment: are you looking for recursive function?
var sumFunc = function(el){
  if(el){
  sum=sum+el;
  sumFunc(nextIterator().next()); 
  } else{return sum;}
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your aim is to take an iterator and sum up all its yielded values, that can easily be done with a simple loop:

```
 function sum(iterator) {
   let value, done, sum = 0;
   do {
    ({value, done} = iterator.next());
    sum += value || 0;
   } while(!done)
   return sum;
}

function* iter() { yield 1; yield 2; yield 3; }
sum(iter()) // 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Yup, this is *the* example used for [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

`[1, 2, 3, 4].reduce((sum, number) => sum + number)`

> The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single value.

---

***Edit:*** If you want an empty array to evaluate to `0` (rather than error), pass an initial value:

`[1, 2, 3, 4].reduce((sum, number) => sum + number, 0)`

Comment: Do not forget to pass the proper initial value.

Comment: Not required. "If no initial value is supplied, the first element in the array will be used."

Comment: If no initial value is supplied, the code will not work for all valid inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array's reduce function to achieve this.

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var sum = a.reduce( (a,b) => a + b);//sum will be 10
```

Comment: Do not forget to pass the proper initial value.