# How can I sum all unique numbers of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've the following data:

```
var array = [2, 4, 12, 4, 3, 2, 2, 5, 0];
```

I want to sum `2 + 4 + 12 + 3 + 5` and want to show the result using JavaScript without any library, by simply using a `for` loop and `if`/`else` statements.

Comment: not common means, *for me*, `12 + 5 + 0` ... what you are looking for, is the sum of all unique numbers.

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of ES6 [`Sets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method of arrays:

```js
let array = [2, 4, 12, 4, 3, 2, 2, 5, 0];

let sum = [...new Set(array)].reduce((a, c) => (a + c), 0);

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: wow! Good to work with this method,But I want to use only for loop and if else statement.

Comment: @Hasanuzzaman Why would you not use the sleeker method? What browsers are you targeting?

Comment: @Hasanuzzaman See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates) for more detailed answers.

Comment: @Hasanuzzaman And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers) one too.

Answer (score 2):

you can try following using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var array = [2,4,12,4,3,2,2,5,0];
let set = new Set();
let sum = array.reduce((a,c) => {
  if(!set.has(c)) {set.add(c); a += c; } 
  return a;
}, 0);
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: function houseNumbersSum(inputArray) {
  return inputArray.slice(0, inputArray.indexOf(0)).reduce((s, v) => s+v, 0);
};houseNumbersSum(inputArray)
//It works good also.

Comment: @Hasanuzzaman - There are many ways to achieve it. However, the above will not remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const distinct = (array) =>
  array ? array.reduce((arr, item) => (arr.find(i => i === item) ? [...arr] : [...arr, item]), []) : array;
  

const sum = distinct([2,4,12,4,3,2,2,5,0]).reduce((a,b) => a + b);

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution using a loop:

```js
const array = [2, 4, 12, 4, 3, 2, 2, 5, 0];

function sumNotCommon(array) {
    const sortedArray = array.slice().sort();
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < sortedArray.length; ++i) {
        if (i === 0 || sortedArray[i] !== sortedArray[i-1])
            sum += sortedArray[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

console.log(sumNotCommon(array));
```

First it sorts the array and then iterates through it ignoring equal numbers that follow each other.