# Sum of numbers in an array with javascript

Tags: javascript, sum

I am trying to get the sum of all the numbers in an array. I am trying to do it in the most simple way but the sum display NAN. why is this so? please help

```js
var numbers = [45, 34, 12, 10, 8, 9];
var i;

for(i=0 ; i<numbers.length; i++){
  var sum = sum + numbers[i];
  //alert(sum);
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="The sum is" + sum;
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript</h2>
<p>This example finds the sum of all numbers in an array:</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: You should define `sum` in out of `for` in  global scope

Comment: `sum` needs to be initialised outside of the loop with 0: `var sum = 0;`

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks! :). I did not initialize the variable..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new `sum` variable for each loop iteration, also you are using it before it's declared hence `undefined + <some numer>` giving you `NaN`

```js
var total = 0;
[45, 34, 12, 10, 8, 9].forEach(num => {total += num});

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=`The sum is: ${total}`;
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript</h2>
<p>This example finds the sum of all numbers in an array:</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Also, nice hack with for loop:

```js
var total = 0;
var numbers = [45, 34, 12, 10, 8, 9];
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; total += numbers[i++]);

console.log('total', total);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var sum = [1, 2, 3].reduce(add, 0);
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
console.log(sum); // 6
```

Comment: This is just a reduced copy of this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers) question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're declaring the sum variable inside the loop and you don't initialize it.

So you get `undefined + numbers[i]` which equals `NaN`.

```js
var numbers = [45, 34, 12, 10, 8, 9];
var i;
var sum = 0;

for(i=0 ; i<numbers.length; i++){
sum = sum + numbers[i];
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="The sum is" + sum;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `sum` is defined outside the scope of your function, so what you're actually doing is `var sum = undefined + numbers[i]` (which is `NaN`).

Even then, it is better to use either [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) or arrow functions (if you can use ES6).

**Using `reduce()`:**

```js
var numbers = [45, 34, 12, 10, 8, 9],
    sum     = numbers.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
    
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = sum;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

**Using arrow functions**:

```js
var numbers = [45, 34, 12, 10, 8, 9],
    sum     = numbers.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = sum;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You're instantiating sum each time, take var sum out the loop and jut have sum.

Also you could use Array.prototype.reduce:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: Please check other answers.

Comment: Putting some codes inside your answer can make your answer attractive.