# add up numbers in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I've been following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers) post but I cannot get my array to add up all numbers in my array.

I use this:

```
 var array_new = [$(".rightcell.emphasize").text().split('€')];
```

to give me this array:

```
array_new: ,102.80,192.60,22.16
```

then I do this:

```
var sum = array_new.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  console.log(sum); //gives me this 0,102.80,192.60,22.16
```

When all I want to do is add up the numbers, I get this result **0,102.80,192.60,22.16.** Can anyone advise me?

Comment: You are creating an array within an array by putting square brackets around your assignment of `array_new`. Try this: `var array_new = $(".rightcell.emphasize").text().split('€');`

Comment: Show us the relevant text in `$(".rightcell.emphasize")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your array is composed of `undefined` and a bunch of strings you have to parse the values to get the numbers. The answer would be:

```js
var data = [,'102.80','192.60','22.16'];

console.log(data.reduce((r,c) => r + parseFloat(c), 0))
```

However if you do not want to deal with the parsing in that function you can make sure that your array comes out as array of numbers like this:

```
Array.from([$(".rightcell.emphasize").text().split('€')], (x) => parseFloat(x || 0))
```

Which would get your array ready for summation and without the need to parse inside the `Array.reduce`. So it would be something like this:

```js
var strings = [,'102.80','192.60','22.16'];
var numbers = Array.from(strings, (x) => parseFloat(x || 0))

console.log(numbers.reduce((r,c) => r + c, 0))
```

But in your case it would be shorter since you would do the first 2 lines as one as shown in the 2nd code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your original array is a string array.

Use `parseFloat` to create numbers from the strings.

```
var strArr = ['102.80','192.60','22.16'];
var sum = strArr.reduce((a,b) => a + parseFloat(b),0); // 317.56
```

Comment: Why create a new array with `map()`?

Comment: just for the example..if your into optimizations then you should use for instead of reduce.

Comment: Also the outer `[]` shouldn't be there

Answer (score 0):

Your elements in the array are treated as strings, therefore the **+** in your reduce function concatenates the array elements into another string. Try to use `parseFloat()` to treat them as numbers:

```
var sum = array_new.reduce((a, b) => a + parseFloat(b), 0);
```

EDIT: Thanks to [charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) who mentioned, that `parseFloat(a)` is redundant, fixed it.

EDIT: (since you already deleted your comment, here would be the solution for your problem): in your case this solution won't work, because one of your array elements is "" (an empty string) which can't be treated as a number, so you could map your array values before you try to add them up:

```
array_new.map(a => (a == "") ? "0" : a);
```

Comment: `parseFloat(a)` is redundant since accumulator is number

Answer (score 0):

in javascript, you can concat numbers by + or strings as well .
I will give you an example :

```
var x = "2" + "1"; // x = 21
var x = 2 + 1 ; // x = 3
```

You can look to [this](http://www.yorku.ca/nmw/datt1939f16/javascript_all/js_stringsNnumbers.html).

You should convert your array to integers (parseInt) or floats(parseFloat) 
in this function array_new.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
It will be something like

```
array_new.reduce((a, b) => a + parseInt(b), 0);//or
array_new.reduce((a, b) => a + parseFloat(b), 0);
```