# how to get sum of filtered array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

So in my google sheet i have some data:
in column A i have dates
in column B i have numbers

also i have 2 cells with starting date and end date which i use to filter array.

What i need to get the sum of filtered numbers. Please help

```
function filteredSum(){

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var tsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

 var originalData = tsheet.getRange(10, 1, tsheet.getLastRow()-1, 2).getValues();
 var mindate = tsheet.getRange("C8").getValue();//starting date
 var maxdate = tsheet.getRange("D8").getValue();//end date

  var data = originalData.filter(function(item){return item[0] >= mindate && item[0] <= maxdate});


  Logger.log(data);
//here i got the array of arrays. and i'm stuck. how to get the sum of numbers

 }
```

Comment: [Read up on the `reduce()` function of the `Array` object on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: Thanks. i did it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the sum of an array of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

```
var sum = data.reduce(function(a,b){
  return a + b[1];
}, 0);
```