# how to compare sum of two values in array in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, comparison

Basically I have two arrays. They are sorted. I have managed to compare them  with efficiency. Now I require to find the sum of two values of arrays and compare them.
For example

```
arr1 = [5,8,10] // sum of first two is 13
arr2 = [6,7,12] // sum of first two is also 13
```

if that happens, do something. 
I can't think of a way to do that.
Any help will highly be appreciated.

Comment: do you always need to compare first two elements of arrays?? Are both arrays always non empty with atleast two elements?

Comment: `arr1.slice(0,2).reduce((sum,item) => sum+=item) == arr2.slice(0,2).reduce((sum,item) => sum+=item)`

Comment: What have you done until now? Do share your code.

Comment: yes I need to compare first two elements. And yes both arrays will always be non-empty

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg why are you using such heavy functions like slice when it is simple if statement.

Comment: @NavjotSingh : I'm assuming, it's not just sum of the first two items in the real example, so my code can be easily scaled

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg Aha...you sure? you just used 2 as a value in your slice function which makes an assumption that you are going for first two elements.

Comment: @NavjotSingh : have array of 1k items and need to sum up 500 of these, would that be easier to type those manually or swap '2' for '500'?

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg I am sure OP didn't intend that.

Comment: @NavjotSingh : Well, I can't beat that - establishing telepathic connection is none of my skills

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If only value from first 2 index is what you required , then you can get the index and do the summation

```js
let arr1 = [5, 8, 10],
  arr2 = [6, 7, 12];

if (arr1[0] + arr1[1] === arr2[0] + arr2[1]) {
  console.log(true)

}
```

Comment: thank you. this will solve my problem.

Comment: @MSafdarAliKhan Thanks , happy to help

Answer (score -1):

try using reduce on the two array with your own rule

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce
[How to find the sum of an array of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers)