# how to get sum of total value in array inside for loop in ext js

Tags: javascript, extjs, sum

Inside the for loop I m getting this data

This values getting from EXT js store.

```
  var sum = results.rows.item(i).Count;
  console.log(sum);
```

in the result, it showing

2

5

6

3

I need a total count of this sum in a single variable. Anybody can answer this, please.
It's a javascript function.

Comment: I just need total count of these values.

Comment: Save all values inside an array, then to a Array.reduce on it. (Like shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43363105/3020926)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce) function for that:

```js
let array = [2,5,6,3];


// will reduce an array to a single variable.
let sum = array.reduce((collector, num) => {
  // the collector is kept for each iteration
  return collector += num;
}, 0 /* initial value is 0 */);

console.log(sum)
```

Comment: i need a javascript function for this. I couldn't get this one

Comment: extjs has built in function for this already, no need for extra javascript.

Answer (score 0):

just use ExtJS's inbuilt function on the store object:

```
myStore.sum('items'); // assuming 'items' is the field you need to sum
```

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#method-sum

if it's a grouped store you can also get sum of group.