# How to get the average value of array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm writing a code that lets you type in 10 random numbers into a prompt window. The numbers are stored in an array called `tal`. I have figured out how to get the highest and the lowest value but I can't get the average. can someone help me with a solution or to get me on the right way?

Here's my code:

```js
let tal = [];
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  tal[i] = prompt('Add a number: ', '');
  tal.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b
  });
}
document.body.innerHTML += Math.max.apply(null, tal) + '<br>';
document.body.innerHTML += Math.min.apply(null, tal) + '<br>';
```

Comment: why do you sort the array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the sum of an array of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers) Use this and then just divide by array.length (basic average calc in math)

Comment: You can calculate the average like this: `var average = eval(numbers.map(Number).join('+'))/numbers.length` where `numbers` is the variable which contains your numbers

Answer (score 6):

I think if you use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to sum up the numbers first then dividing that number with the length you are getting the average of the numbers at the end.

From the documentation of `Array.prototype.reduce()`:

> The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in a single output value.

```js
const numbers = [3,4,5,2,4,6,78,53,2,1,2];
const sum = numbers.reduce((a,c) => a + c, 0);
const avg = sum / numbers.length;

console.log(avg);
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: this is the simplest solution and correct as long as you have reduce available (meaning you are not writing for IE). Otherwise the first answer using a for loop would have to be used.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
var average = getAverage(tal);

function getAverage(arr) {
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum += Number(arr[i]);
  }

  return sum / arr.length;
}
```