# Get sum of numbers inside ONE variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to add different numbers inside **one** variable?

Example:

```css
$( ".list .task" ).each( function( ){ 
  var GetScore = $( this ).text();
  console.log(GetScore);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <div class="list">
  <div class="task">1</div>
</div>
<div class="list">
  <div class="task">2.2</div>
</div>
<div class="list">
  <div class="task">4</div>
</div>
<div class="list">
  <div class="task">9.3</div>
</div>
```

Like this way I get the numbers in one variable, but how can I add them now? Or is it necessary to make a variable for every `".task"` number?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the sum of an array of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers)

Comment: @Azametzin Thx for the tip / link, I will take a look.

Comment: @Azametzin I think your link only works with [arrays].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you declare a variable for the initial value.
Then inside the function, you add to this value each number if it exists.

```js
var GetScore = 0; // initial value

$( ".list .task" ).each( function(){    
    GetScore += parseFloat($(this).text()) || 0;
});

console.log(GetScore); // 16.5
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div class="task">1</div>
</div>
<div class="list">
  <div class="task">2.2</div>
</div>
<div class="list">
  <div class="task">4</div>
</div>
<div class="list">
  <div class="task">9.3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read about [JavaScript Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).
Alternative and better practice for your needs - create a variable and name it like `total`, initiate it with the value of `0`.
Then for every jQuery.each loop, add the element's value to the `total` variable.
For example:

```
var total = 0;

$( ".list .task" ).each( function(){    
    total += parseInt($( this ).text());
});

console.log(total);
```

Comment: Hm, its not working for me - I have to fgure out why ... but thx for the tip / link.

Comment: Please try using the `innerHTML` function instead of the `text` function.

Comment: Now its working, but as info, you have some fails in your script. And at the end, with this way I also get only every number, not the sum.