# Simple Array Sum using javascript (single integer)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum, integer

Been finding the this sum difficult to solve:

Question:
Given an array of integers, find the sum of its elements.

For example, if the array ar = [1,2.3],1+2+3=6 so return 6.

Function Description

Complete the simpleArraySum function in the editor below. It must return the sum of the array elements as an integer.

I have tried:

```
function simpleArraySum(ar) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <ar.length; i++) {
    sum += (ar);
    return sum;
    }
}
```

Output is: 01,2,3,4,10,11

It should be 31.

Help please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the sum of an array of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers)

Comment: What is `sum += (ar)` supposed to do? `sum` is a number and `ar` an array. And why is `return sum` _in_ the loop?

Comment: Two problems with your code: `sum += (ar);` tries to add the **array** `ar` to `sum`. You have to access the individual elements of the array instead (that's why you are using a loop). `return sum;` inside the loop will terminate the function (and therefore the loop) in the first iteration of the loop. Only return the sum *after* you have processed all array elements.

Comment: `arr.reduce((a,v) => a + v ,0)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems in your code. You need to change

`sum += (ar);` to `sum +=  (ar[i]);`

so as to sum the element at that index and not the `ar` itself. Also `return` should be outside the loop and should actually be the return of the function. Otherwise, `for..loop` will just return after the first execution.

```js
function simpleArraySum(ar) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    if(typeof ar[i] == `number`) sum += ar[i];
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(simpleArraySum([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Comment: why not omit parentese around the value of the array. it is superfluous and irritating, because it has no reason.