# Calculating sum of array using O(logn) time complexity

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

I have an array of **n** characters. To calculate the sum of the array I have used the following code snippet:

```
  var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  var i = 0;
  var j = arr.length - 1;
  var sum = 0;
  while(i<j || i==j){
     sum = sum + ((i==j) ? arr[i] : arr[i] + arr[j])
     i++;
     j--;
  }
```

I have used two pointers **i** and **j** to traverse the array from both directions and it finds the sum.  I wanted to know whether this is a correct approach and does it run in O(log n) time complexity?

Thanks

Comment: your code runs in n/2 => O(n) time complexity.

Comment: You can simply put a counter in your while loop. With an array of 100, that counter would be 50, while if it were O(log n) it would be closer to `Math.log2(100)` ~=  6. If you could find a way to do this in `O(log n)` for arbitrary arrays you would become famous.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers

Comment: As you need to read all *n* values to calculate the sum, you cannot possibly get below O(n), whichever the order with which you read those values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it may seem like the complexity of your algorithm is less than `O(N)`, it is actually still is `O(N)`. Since you are only incrementing/decrementing by a factor of 1, the number of iterations in your loop would be about `N / 2` which is `O(N)`.

You would achieve `O(log N)` time complexity if you disregarded half of N after each iteration as shown in an algorithm like binary search.

For this summation problem, you can actually solve in `O(1)` time by using math. See: [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF).

EDIT: you can only use math for 1 to N