# How to select all of a particular values of key from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

so im trying to find a more efficient way to write the following code.

`cartState.forEach((cart) => subTotal += cart.price);`

I feel like if cartState is quite large, and becuase each cart object is quite large in itself. so purely performance or best practices is there a better way to do this?

Heres the array

```
const cartState = [
    {
      name: 'xxx',
      price: 'xxx',
    },
]
```

Just as an edit, this isn't just for adding totals, it's also for combining values into an array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the sum of an array of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers)

Comment: In this particular case yeah, but i will also be using it for adding values into an array if they're not numbers ie 
```cartState.forEach((cart) => items.push(name));```

Comment: You need to go through each object and access a property one way or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By efficient did you mean the fastest computation time or readability?
If you want the fastest solution, try a for loop, because all the other options i.e. map/reduce/forEach are much slower than for loop. You can find [here](https://dev.to/henryjw/array-map-much-slower-than-for-loop-57if).

Comment: Functionally i'd like to know the fasted comp time so thanks for that, however out of curiosity what would be best for readability?

Comment: `reduce` would be