# Arrays - Finding Sums within

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am relatively new to coding.  I am working on arrays.  I am trying to add within an array.  I have 6 different track lengths and I want my output to be the total of all six tracks.  How do I combine information within my array?

Comment: Add snippet of your array and desired result.

Comment: what programming language?

Comment: let trackTimes = [181, 213, 195, 153, 288, 203, 174];
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Do not change anything above here.
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/*
  Update the `albumRuntime` variable to be the sum value of all items in the `trackTimes` array. Use bracket notation to access each value of the `trackTimes` array. Then add all of those values together.
*/
albumRuntime = trackTimes;

Comment: I am working in Java Script.  My goal is to have a total sum for the entire array

Comment: tevemadar's answer is pretty sufficient for a beginner. But just FYI, you can also do `const totalTrackTime = trackTimes.reduce((c, it) => c + it)`, which would return the same answer using the functional `.reduce()` API.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment...

> ```
> let trackTimes = [181, 213, 195, 153, 288, 203, 174];
> //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
> // Do not change anything above here. > 
> //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
> /* Update the albumRuntime variable to be the sum value of all items in the trackTimes
> array. Use bracket notation to access each value of the trackTimes array. Then
> add all of those values together. */
> ```

...the most classic way is expected to be used here: loop an `index` variable over the `length` of the array, and use `trackTimes[index]` to access each element, adding it to the sum `albumRuntime`, which should be started with a zero:

```js
let trackTimes = [181, 213, 195, 153, 288, 203, 174];
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Do not change anything above here. > 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

let albumRuntime = 0;
for(let index = 0; index < trackTimes.length; index++) {
  albumRuntime = albumRuntime + trackTimes[index];
}
console.log(albumRuntime);
```

For a rather large collection of array-summing snippets with different techniques, see [How to find the sum of an array of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers)

Side remark: it's better to add such details directly intto the question itself, there is an [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66409967/edit) button/link just below it.