# REACT JS - How to do a summation inside a map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function, array-map

originally I was gonna ask how to call a function inside a map but I realize I wasn't doing anything wrong in the way I was calling my function so I just think that my code is wrong.

So I'm trying to do a summation of all the prices of a map i'm rendering sometimes those prices change due to the quantity that the person might want so I was calling:

```
//My function call inside the map
{calculateTotal(fixedPrice)}

//The function
const calculateTotal = (price) => {
        setTotalPrice (totalPrice + price)
      }
```

But I got this error in return

[image]

I don't understand how adding 2 numbers certain amount of times (in this case 9) would end up in an infinite loop. All I want to do is to sum all the prices into one variable and if the cantidad/quantity changes it add those changes too.

[image]

whole code in case you need it

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { auth, db } from './firebase';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Checkbox } from '@material-ui/core';

function CrearPedidos({user}) {
    const [libros, setLibros] = useState([]);
    const [cantidad, setCantidad] = useState( new Array(libros.length).fill(1));

    useEffect(()=>{
      setCantidad(new Array(libros.length).fill(1))
    }, [libros])

    const history = useHistory("");
    const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState();

    const librosRef = db.collection('libros');
    const queryRef = librosRef.where('grado', '==', '4° Grado');

    useEffect(() => {
        queryRef.orderBy("precio")
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
              const tempData = [];
            snapshot.forEach((doc) => {

              const data = doc.data();
              tempData.push(data);
            });
            setLibros(tempData);
          });
      }, []);

      const mas = (index) => {
        setCantidad(cantidad[index]++);
        setCantidad([...cantidad])
      };

      const menos = (index) => {
        if (cantidad[index] > 0){
            setCantidad(cantidad[index]--);
            setCantidad([...cantidad])
        }
        else {
            window.alert("Sorry, Zero limit reached");
        }
      };

      const calculateTotal = (price) => {
        setTotalPrice (totalPrice + price)
      }

    return (
        <div className="listado_Pedidos"> 
        <div className="estudiantes_container">
            <h1 className = "estudiantes_container_h1">Estudiante: {user.displayName}</h1>
            <h1 className = "estudiantes_container_h1">Libros Nuevos</h1>
            <div className ="tableContainer">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr className="Lista">
                        <th>Cantidad</th>
                        <th>Grado</th>
                        <th>Descripcion</th>
                        <th>Editorial</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {libros.map((libros, index, fixedPrice) => (
                        <tr key={libros.id || index}>
                        <td>
                            <button onClick = {() => mas(index)}/>
                            {cantidad[index]}
                            {console.log(cantidad)}
                            <button onClick = {() => menos(index)}/>
                        </td>
                        <td>{libros.grado}</td>

                        <td >
                        <input onChange = {(event) => {
                            let checked = event.target.checked;
                        }} 
                        
                        type="checkbox" checked = "">
                        </input>
                        {libros.descripcion}
                        </td>

                        <td >{libros.editorial}</td>
                        <td >${fixedPrice = parseFloat(libros.precio).toFixed(2) * cantidad[index]}</td>
                        
                        {calculateTotal(fixedPrice)}
                        </tr>
                        
                     ))
                     }
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>

            <div className="space" />
            <button onClick="{realizarPedidos}" className = "crear_estudiante_boton">Realizar Pedidos</button>
            <div className="space" />
      </div>

      </div>
    )
}

export default CrearPedidos
```

Comment: When the content is rendered, it calls `calculateTotal`, which calls `setTotalPrice`, which causes the component to re-render, which calls `calculateTotal`, which calls `setTotalPrice`, which causes the component to re-render, which calls `calculateTotal` ... and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about two theoretical points.

1. You must notice that `map` returns an array of values. So if you call a function, it will be call multiple times.
2. In React, when state changes, component will re-render on every change. In `map` you call a function that changes state. Then state changing re-render all component. Again the `map` call that function , again and again. And this is an infinity loop.

If you want count total price, must do it outside of map return.

**Separate logic. Do all countings outside of component `return`. Then in component return just show jsx elements**

Comment: But then how I get access to the values of the map ?

Comment: Separate logic. Do all countings outside of component `return`. Then in component return just show jsx elements

Comment: but if I separe it I can't no longer get access to the Map data that comes from the database from firebase D:

Comment: https://commercejs.com/docs/community/creating-a-cart-with-react-js/

Answer (score 1):

As @Danial said, you're updating state so many times, very fastly, which triggers page renderization, and throw the error you got.

To do this summation of all items into the array, use `reduce` array function instead of map.

Reference: [How to find the sum of an array of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers#answer-43363105)

Comment: In one of the examples I see that they do the following: 

`var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var total = 0;
for (var i in arr) {
  total += arr[i];
}`

But when I try that I get N/A D:

Comment: I think it would be better to use the reduce function. Something like that: `libros.map(getPrice).reduce(reduceFunction, 0)`, and then store it in a state named summation. A nice place to put this code is the useEffect with the libros dependency.

Comment: OH I MADE IT WORK but I didn't use Reduce

Answer (score 1):

Hi I just figure it out after trying stuff (Wasn't able to understand reduce properly) this is another approach without using reduce and just using useEffect

```
const [libros, setLibros] = useState([]);
const [cantidad, setCantidad] = useState( new Array(libros.length).fill(1));
const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState([]);

useEffect((i) => {
        let x = 0
        libros.map((i, index) => {
          x += i.precio * cantidad[index]
          setTotalPrice(parseFloat(x).toFixed(2))
        })
      })

... some code

//And then just call the variable
<h1>Precio total: {totalPrice}</h1>
```

This is how it looks!

[image]

It also updates every time the "cantidad" goes up or down!

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines:

```
const [cantidad, setCantidad] = useState(...);
const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState();
```

Instead use `useMemo` hook.

```
const cantidad = useMemo(() => {
  return new Array(libros.length).fill(1);
}, [libros]);

const total = useMemo(() => {
  return libros.reduce((sum, libro, index) => {
    return sum + parseFloat(libro.precio) * cantidad[index];
  }, 0);
}, [cantidad, libros]);
```

And then use it like:

```
<td>{total.tofixed(2)}</td>
```