# C# Adding the sum of 2 Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to add the sum of two arrays that the user filled himself together in a variable or in a third array and then print it out. This is what I am stuck with:

```
Console.Write("How many numbers do you want to add: ");
        int howmany = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
       
        int[] numarr1 = new int[howmany];
        int[] numarr2 = new int[howmany];
        int[] res = new int[1];

        for (int i = 0; i < numarr1.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Input a first number: ");
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            numarr1[i] = a;            
        }
        for(int b = 0; b < numarr2.Length; b++)
        {
            Console.Write("Input a second number: ");
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            numarr1[b] = a;
        }
        int result = numarr1 + numarr2;
```

Everything works except the last line where I try to add them. On the Internet, I was searching for "How to add the sum of two arrays but I didn't really find anything that really solves my problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the sum of an array of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers)

Comment: @Jazb I still don't know how to add them so no.

Comment: find the sum of each array, then add the two sums...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about using [`Linq.Sum()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Sum_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Int32__)

```
int result = numarr1.Sum() + numarr2.Sum();
```

---

or just add the values during iteration

```
Console.Write("How many numbers do you want to add: ");
int howmany = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[] numarr1 = new int[howmany];
int[] numarr2 = new int[howmany];
int[] res = new int[1];
int result = 0; // result here
for (int i = 0; i < numarr1.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Input a first number: ");
    numarr1[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    result += numarr1[i];
}
for (int b = 0; b < numarr2.Length; b++)
{
    Console.Write("Input a second number: ");
    numarr2[b] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    result += numarr2[b];
}
```

Comment: "Sum()" just gets underlined.

Comment: @Connor add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: The result is five when I enter in that I want to add 2 numbers so the first 2 numbers were 2 and 3 and the second 2 numbers were 2 and 3 too, but the result is 5, it must be 10.

Comment: @Connor side note, you have a bug in your code, the second `for` loop uses `numarr1` instead of `numarr2`