# Trying to add each element of array to the next one for unknown number of elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, integer-arithmetic

Something like this but generalized

```
let arr = [6, 5, 4, 3];
let i = 0, j = 0;
let result = [];

    result.push(arr[0]+arr[1],
arr[2]+arr[3]);

console.log(result
```

Comment: What if there is an odd number of items in the array? did you try to implement a loop to do it?

Comment: This seems very much like a duplicate of: "[How to find the sum of an array of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1230233/82548)," have you tried the solutions offered there, or is there something unique in this problem that you haven't fully explained?

Comment: This is for a simple hash exercise on codewars I have to add an array of char codes each to the next in the array then base64encode new char

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring last element if array has odd number of elements:

```js
function f(arr) {
  let result = [];
  for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
     if (i % 2==0 && i<arr.length-1) {
        result.push(arr[i] + arr[i+1]);
        i++;
     }
  };
  return result;
}

let arr = [6, 5, 4, 3];

console.log(f(arr));
console.log(f([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]));
```

Comment: Im almost there how would I and index[0] + index[1] , index[1] + index[2] and so on

Comment: So an array of length *n* becomes a new array of length *n*-1?

Comment: `let result = []; for (let i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++) result.push(arr[i] + arr[i+1]); return result;`