# Using Reduce method

Tags: javascript, reduce

I just started learning about reduce method, and stuck in this problem...

```
  N   answer
123   6
987   24
```

An example would be 9 + 8 + 7 = 24 but the parameter is in number.

Here is what I have tried:

```
function solution (n){
   let result = new Array (n)
   let answer = result.reduce((a,b) => {
       return a + b 
   })
}
```

Here is my code but I'm getting `TypeError [Error]: Reduce of empty array with no initial value`

Comment: you instantiated an empty array of size n. It doesn't contains anything. You input is a string so convert it to a array of char n.split('') or [...n] or Array.from(n) then you can do map to int and use your reduce operation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the sum of an array of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers)

Comment: this-> `(''+123).split('').reduce((acc,n)=>acc+=parseInt(n),0);`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you would use reduce to calculate the sum -

```
[...String(123)].map(Number).reduce((a,b) => a+b, 0)
```

Comment: Wow, I love this. Please elaborate and explain to the OP *why* this works.

Comment: Also, I believe you don't need the `0`.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
let result = new Array (n)
```

creates an empty array with a length of `n`.

In order to convert a number to an array of digits, you can use this little handy snippet:

```
const arr = n.toString().split('').map(Number)
```

We are getting `n` as a string, then splitting it into an array of characters, and then mapping each character to its corresponding digit.

After that you can use the `reduce` function:

```
let answer = arr.reduce((a,b) => {
    return a + b 
});
```