# How to create a new object from existing entries?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, mapping, reduce

I am trying to create an object that will be filled with values from an existing object. In my case it should have as result per "Material" an object list with the "Code" and the "Quantity". In addition, if the "Material" and "Code" are the same, the "Quantity" should be summed up.
I hope that you can see from my example what I mean. Thanks

```js
const arr = [{
  "Material": "123",
  "Code": "AAA",
  "Quantity": 1
}, {
  "Material": "123",
  "Code": "BBB",
  "Quantity": 2
}, {
  "Material": "123",
  "Code": "BBB",
  "Quantity": 2
}, {
  "Material": "456",
  "Code": "CCC",
  "Quantity": 7
}]

var arrResult = [{
  "Material": "123",
  "CodeQuantity": [{
    "Code": "AAA",
    "Quantity": 1
  }, {
    "Code": "BBB",
    "Quantity": 4
  }]
}, {
  "Material": "456",
  "CodeQuantity": [{
    "Code": "CCC",
    "Quantity": 7
  }]
}]

console.log(arr)
console.log("Result:", arrResult)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I group an array of objects by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-can-i-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key) - it may not be exact, but it should help you get 80% there

Comment: The questions is how to sum the values if "Material" and "Code" matches?

Comment: The question I linked to has all sorts of suggestions about how to group the values. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers shows how to sum them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach should consider breaking the OP's entire task into two separate ones.

Within an intermediate step one firstly does [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the list of material items into a map of (grouped) material items.

The final step does a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)-`reduce` on the [`values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) of the intermediate result, where the `reduce` task is responsible for summing up a material's `Code` specific `Quantity` value ...

```js
function collectTotalCodeQuantity(index, item) {
  const { Code, Quantity } = item;

  // access or create the `Code` specific code quantity item.
  const codeQuantityItem = (index[Code] ??= { Code, Quantity: 0 });
  // sum up a `Code` specific code quantity item's quantity value.
  codeQuantityItem.Quantity += Quantity;

  return index;
}
function createMaterialGroup(index, item) {
  const { Material: materialValue, ...rest } = item;
  // create the `CodeQuantity` key in a more generic way from the
  // `rest` object which is ... `item` data without `Material` property.
  const compoundKey = Object.keys(rest).join('');

  // access or create the `Material` specific group.
  const group = index[materialValue] ??= { Material: materialValue };
  // access or create the `CodeQuantity` specific list.
  const list = group[compoundKey] ??= [];

  // push the `rest` object into the `CodeQuantity` specific list.
  list.push(rest);
  return index;
}

const materialDataItemList = [{
  "Material": "123",
  "Code": "AAA",
  "Quantity": 1
}, {
  "Material": "123",
  "Code": "BBB",
  "Quantity": 2
}, {
  "Material": "123",
  "Code": "BBB",
  "Quantity": 2
}, {
  "Material": "456",
  "Code": "AAA",
  "Quantity": 7
}];

const totalCodeQuantityItemList = Object
  .values(
    materialDataItemList.reduce(createMaterialGroup, {})
  )
  .map(materialGroup => {
    materialGroup.CodeQuantity = Object.values(
      materialGroup.CodeQuantity.reduce(collectTotalCodeQuantity, {})
    );
    return materialGroup;
  });

console.log({ totalCodeQuantityItemList });
console.log(
  '... intermediate process result ... map of (grouped) material items ...',
  materialDataItemList.reduce(createMaterialGroup, {})
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

***Edit***

> *Moin! how can I add a new key "CodeQuantityGesamt" where the values of all "Quantity" of a "Material" is summed? example:*
>
> ```
> {
>   "Material": "123",
>   "CodeQuantityGesamt": 5,
>   "CodeQuantity": [{
>     "Code": "AAA",
>     "Quantity": 1
>   }, {
>     "Code": "BBB",
>     "Quantity": 4
>   }]
> }
> ```
>
> *– InFlames82*

This can be achieved by changing the mapping task from ...

```
.map(materialGroup => {
  materialGroup.CodeQuantity = Object.values(
    materialGroup.CodeQuantity.reduce(collectTotalCodeQuantity, {})
  );
  return materialGroup;
});
```

... to e.g. ...

```
.map(materialGroup => Object.assign(
  materialGroup,
  materialGroup.CodeQuantity.reduce(collectCodeQuantityTotals, {})
));
```

... together with adapting the implementation and changing the name of the former `collectTotalCodeQuantity` reducer function which becomes `collectCodeQuantityTotals`.

```js
function collectCodeQuantityTotals(quantities, item, idx, arr) {
  const { Code, Quantity } = item;
  let {
    CodeQuantityTotal = 0,
    CodeQuantity = [],
    index = {},
  } = quantities;

  // access ...
  let codeQuantityItem = index[Code];
  // ... or create the `Code` specific code quantity item.
  if (!codeQuantityItem) {
    codeQuantityItem = index[Code] = { Code, Quantity: 0 };

    // push a newly created item into the CodeQuantity list.
    CodeQuantity.push(codeQuantityItem);
  }
  // sum up a `Code` specific code quantity item's quantity value.
  codeQuantityItem.Quantity += Quantity;

  // sum up the total (or overall) code quantity value.
  CodeQuantityTotal += Quantity;

  // return a full collector/accumulator object as long as
  // the reduce task takes place because `index` is needed
  // as lookup, but return, as the final result, an object
  // without the `index` property.
  return (idx < arr.length - 1)
    && { CodeQuantityTotal, CodeQuantity, index }
    || { CodeQuantityTotal, CodeQuantity };
}
function createMaterialGroup(index, item) {
  const { Material: materialValue, ...rest } = item;
  // create the `CodeQuantity` key in a more generic way from the
  // `rest` object which is ... `item` data without `Material` property.
  const compoundKey = Object.keys(rest).join('');

  // access or create the `Material` specific group.
  const group = index[materialValue] ??= { Material: materialValue };
  // access or create the `CodeQuantity` specific list.
  const list = group[compoundKey] ??= [];

  // push the `rest` object into the `CodeQuantity` specific list.
  list.push(rest);
  return index;
}

const materialDataItemList = [{
  "Material": "123",
  "Code": "AAA",
  "Quantity": 1
}, {
  "Material": "123",
  "Code": "BBB",
  "Quantity": 2
}, {
  "Material": "123",
  "Code": "BBB",
  "Quantity": 2
}, {
  "Material": "456",
  "Code": "AAA",
  "Quantity": 7
}];

const totalCodeQuantityItemList = Object
  .values(
    materialDataItemList.reduce(createMaterialGroup, {})
  )
  .map(materialGroup => Object.assign(
    materialGroup,
    materialGroup.CodeQuantity.reduce(collectCodeQuantityTotals, {})
  ));

console.log({ totalCodeQuantityItemList });
console.log(
  '... intermediate process result ... map of (grouped) material items ...',
  materialDataItemList.reduce(createMaterialGroup, {})
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Moin! how can I add a new key "CodeQuantityGesamt" where the values of all "Quantity" of a "Material" is summed? example: {
      "Material": "123", "CodeQuantityGesamt": 5,
      "CodeQuantity": [
        {
          "Code": "AAA",
          "Quantity": 1
        },
        {
          "Code": "BBB",
          "Quantity": 4
        }
      ]
    }

Comment: @InFlames82 ... Tach och! ... one has to change the 2nd task, the final mapping, according to the new requirement(s). The edit of the above answer does demonstrate how it can be achieved. And in order to comment on the downvote ... _**the easy refactoring of the first implementation also proves the reliability/robustness of the underlying approach**_.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```js
const arr = [{
  "Material": "123",
  "Code": "AAA",
  "Quantity": 1
}, {
  "Material": "123",
  "Code": "BBB",
  "Quantity": 2
}, {
  "Material": "123",
  "Code": "BBB",
  "Quantity": 2
}, {
  "Material": "456",
  "Code": "CCC",
  "Quantity": 7
}];

let group = arr.reduce((r, a) => {
  r[a.Material] = [...r[a.Material] || [], a];
  return r;
}, {});



 var newArr = Object.keys(group).map(key => {
        var elem = group[key];
        var b = elem.map(e => {
            return {
                Code: e.Code,
                Quantity: e.Quantity

            }
        });
        var filteredArr = [];
        b.map(i => {
            var item = filteredArr.find(n => n.Code == i.Code);
            if (item) {
                item.Quantity += i.Quantity;
            } else {
                filteredArr.push(i);
            }
        })
        return {
            Material: key,
            CodeQuantity: filteredArr
        }
    });
    console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Please note, the output doesn't match what the asker wants.

Comment: Then please may you also explain how your answer works?

Answer (score -2):

Updated the solution to match your expectation.
This this. Hope it solves your use case.

```js
const arr = [{
  "Material": "123",
  "Code": "AAA",
  "Quantity": 1
}, {
  "Material": "123",
  "Code": "BBB",
  "Quantity": 2
}, {
  "Material": "123",
  "Code": "BBB",
  "Quantity": 2
}, {
  "Material": "456",
  "Code": "CCC",
  "Quantity": 7
}]

var arrResultExpected = [{
  "Material": "123",
  "CodeQuantity": [{
    "Code": "AAA",
    "Quantity": 1
  }, {
    "Code": "BBB",
    "Quantity": 4
  }]
}, {
  "Material": "456",
  "CodeQuantity": [{
    "Code": "CCC",
    "Quantity": 7
  }]
}]

//console.log(arr)
//console.log("ExpecredResult:", arrResultExpected)

const materialIds = arr.map(a => a.Material);
//console.log(materialIds);
const dedupedMaterialIds = [...new Set(materialIds)]
//console.log(dedupedMaterialIds);

const needArr = dedupedMaterialIds.map(entry => {
  const matchingEntries = arr.filter(arrEntry => entry === arrEntry.Material);
  //console.log(matchingEntries);

  var summedResult = [];
  matchingEntries.reduce(function(res, value) {
    if (!res[value.Code]) {
      res[value.Code] = {
        Quantity: 0,
        Code: value.Code
      };
      summedResult.push(res[value.Code])
    }
    res[value.Code].Quantity += value.Quantity
    return res;
  }, {});
  //console.log(summedResult);
  return {
    Material: entry,
    CodeQuantity: [...summedResult]
  };
});


console.log(needArr);
```

Comment: This solution does not sum the "Quantity" if "Material" and "Code" matches

Comment: Updated the solution to match your expectation. @InFlames82