# Sum objects from array in JavaScript (JS)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to sum expense but i dont know how, can somebody explain

```
for (let i = 0; i < ExpensesList.length; i++) {
    const expense = Number(ExpensesList[i][2])
    console.log(expense);
}
```

ExpenseList:

```
0: ["First expense", "2022-02-05", "51"]
1: ["Second expense", "2022-02-05", "5"] 
2: ["Third expense", "2022-02-12", "213"]
```

In console.log i have 51, 5, 213 sum of this is 269 but i dont know how to add that to each other

Comment: create an integer variable and increase it by the expense amount in the loop

Comment: `expenseList.reduce((acc, array) => +array[2] + acc, 0);` if expenseList is an array. If expenseList is an object, do that to `Object.values(expenseList)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the sum of an array of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare a variable (let's call it `sum`) outside of the loop and increment it for each item in within the loop.

You could log it in the loop to see it being increased for each item, but what you want is to use it **after** the loop.

```js
const expensesList = [
  ["First expense", "2022-02-05", "51"],
  ["Second expense", "2022-02-12", "213"]
]

let sum = 0
for (let i = 0; i < expensesList.length; i++) {
    sum += Number(expensesList[i][2])
}

console.log(sum)
```

Btw I also renammed the variable `expensesList`.

Here is another solution with `[].reduce` and some destructuring:

```js
const sum = expensesList.reduce((result, [,,e]) => result + Number(e), 0)
```