# get total sum every count inside array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

It should be a simple task but I'm having a little bit of trouble 
doing it.

I have the following object:

```
{
  "chatRoom": [
    {
      "_count": {
        "publicMessages": 10
      }
    },
    {
      "_count": {
        "publicMessages": 10
      }
    },
    {
      "_count": {
        "publicMessages": 10
      }
    }
  ],
}
```

I would like to get the total sum of every value 
inside "publicMessages" 
The desidered output:

```
{
  "totalMessages": 30
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the sum of an array of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Array.reduce()` function. If that object is inside a variable named `obj`, you can achieve this by using:

```js
const result = {
  totalMessages: obj.chatRoom.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur._count.publicMessages, 0)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Array.reduce() is the solution, you can run it like this:

```js
const obj={chatRoom:[{_count:{publicMessages:10}},{_count:{publicMessages:10}},{_count:{publicMessages:10}}]};

let sum = obj.chatRoom.reduce( (acc, curr)=>{ return acc+=curr._count.publicMessages??0},0);

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: This code does not work in your snippet.

Comment: Right, I just shared a direction to think into, Actual solution will require defining obj and transform sum into expected obj structure

Answer (score 1):

If you want something a little more verbose and understandable than `reduce`, a simple [for/of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement) loop might help you.

```js
const data={chatRoom:[{_count:{publicMessages:10}},{_count:{publicMessages:10}},{_count:{publicMessages:10}}]};

// Initialise the total
let totalMessages = 0;

// Loop over the chatRoom array of objects
// and add the publicMessages value to the total
for (const obj of data.chatRoom) {
  totalMessages += obj._count.publicMessages;
}

// Log the total
console.log({ totalMessages });
```

Comment: Thank you. your answer works well it's problably more performatic as well. but I like fuctional programming and es6 more.

Comment: That's great, and `reduce` is very useful for summing values up. But we see a lot overuse of `reduce` (and one-liners) for code that isn't necessary on this site (I've fallen into that trap :)). Sometimes a simple for/loop is easier to review and debug, particularly if you're working in a team. Happy coding @DiegoBraga.