# Recursion to sum the array! what is wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, recursion

just trying to find the sum in the array and can't figure out what is wrong with my code, if you can help that would be appreciated :)

```
function arraySum(arr, index) {
    if (arr.length <= index)
        return 0;
    return (arraySum(arr, arr.length - 1) + arr[arr.length - 1]);

}
```

I'm trying to find the sum of the array using recursion. what is exactly wrong with my code :) if you can help that would be appreciated

ps index=0 arr.length =8

Comment: Is this a homework problem? Recursion doesn't seem like the best way to do this.

Comment: `arr.length - 1` will always be the same right?

Comment: Use a `console.log()` to print the `arr.length` and `index` to debug the logic. How are you calling this function? If you're calling it with `[1,2,3], 3`, then you can see the base case is hit right away. Why not increase the index from 0 to `arr.length - 1`? The initial call is `(arr, 0)` and you do `index + 1` per recursive call with a base case of `index >= arr.length`. Also, this is a poor usage of recursion -- you'll blow the stack if your array is a few thousand elements.

Comment: are you trying to find the max value or the sum?

Comment: arr.length = 8, i'm tryinig to find the sum sorry, typo

Comment: Issue in return call , i submitted the answer below

Answer (score 0):

```js
function arraySum(arr, index) {
    if (index >= arr.length)
        return 0;
    return (arraySum(arr, index + 1) + arr[index]);
}
```

arr.length - 1 is the same, what you need to do is to iterate through the array, to make it work recursively. recursion needs a terminating point. in your code you are passing arr.length - 1 as index at every call, which remains constant.

Comment: why don't you use reduce to get the sum of array , why are you doing recursion in the first place: function sum(arr) {
  const reducer = (sum, val) => sum + val;
  const initialValue = 0;
  return arr.reduce(reducer, initialValue);
}
sum([1, 3, 5, 7]); // 16

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in the recursion patterns you need a break condition.

Second, in each step of the recursion you need to take a little piece of work, and pass the rest to the others.

You have the break condition but it seems like your little piece of work is missing or not done properly.

Here is how to do that:

```js
var sum = function(arr, currentIndex) {
   if(currentIndex < 0 || currentIndex >= arr.length) return 0;
   return arr[currentIndex] + sum(arr, ++currentIndex);
};

//Test it
var arr = [1, 4, 5];
sum(arr, 0);
```

Comment: `function arraySum(arr, index) {
 if(index < 0 || index >= arr.length) 
  return 0;
 return arr[index] + arraysum(arr, ++index);
}` This didn't work properly but i feel like getting closer

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: There are much better ways of achieving the desired goal:
[How to find the sum of an array of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers)

---

To answer OP's question, here's an other approach using [`pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop):

- If there are more then items in the array `(arr.length > 1)`

  - Return recursive result:
    `(arr.pop() + arraySum(arr))`
- If this was the last item, just return the last value
  `arr.pop()`

Combining this in a [short-if-statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) gives us:

```js
function arraySum(arr) {
    return (arr.length > 1) ? (arr.pop() + arraySum(arr)) : arr.pop();
}
```

---

```js
function arraySum(arr) {
    return (arr.length > 1) ? (arr.pop() + arraySum(arr)) : arr.pop();
}

const arr = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
const res = arraySum(arr);
console.log(res); // 6
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following snippet of code and it is running

```
function arraySum(arr, index) {
  if (index >= arr.length) {
    return 0;
  }
  return arr[index] + arraySum(arr, index + 1)  ;
}
const x = arraySum([1, 2, 3], 0);
console.log(x);
```

[image]

Since this is a simple array if you just need sum you can use reduce method

```
function sum(arr) {
  const reducer = (sum, val) => sum + val;
  const initialValue = 0;
  return arr.reduce(reducer, initialValue);
}

sum([1, 3, 5, 7]); // 16
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
function findSum(A, N) {
    if (N <= 0)
        return 0;
    return (findSum(A, N - 1) + A[N - 1]);
}

 
let A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let N = A.length;
document.write(findSum(A,N));
```

Comment: i tried that code my problem is index = 0