# How to reduce JavaScript code when I'm trying to sum of table colums?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table & I want to total of columns data, this is working fine but now I want to reduce `JavaScript code` how can I do that?

My Code:-

```js
var TotalValue1 = 0;
        var currentRow1 = '';
        $("tr .loop1").each(function(index, value) {
            currentRow1 = parseFloat($(value).text());
            TotalValue1 += currentRow1
        });
        $('.total1').text(TotalValue1);
        
           var TotalValue2 = 0;
        var currentRow2 = '';
        $("tr .loop2").each(function(index, value) {
            currentRow2 = parseFloat($(value).text());
            TotalValue2 += currentRow2
        });
        $('.total2').text(TotalValue2);

        var TotalValue3 = 0;
        var currentRow3 = '';
        $("tr .loop3").each(function(index, value) {
            currentRow3 = parseFloat($(value).text());
            TotalValue3 += currentRow3
        });
        $('.total3').text(TotalValue3);
     
        var TotalValue4 = 0;
        var currentRow4 = '';
        $("tr .loop4").each(function(index, value) {
            currentRow4 = parseFloat($(value).text());
            TotalValue4 += currentRow4
        });
        $('.total4').text(TotalValue4);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Store</th>
        <th>Sale</th>
        <th>Revenu</th>
        <th>Payout</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td class="loop1">20</td>
        <td class="loop2">34</td>
        <td class="loop3">65</td>
        <td class="loop4">26</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td class="loop1">76</td>
        <td class="loop2">93</td>
        <td class="loop3">27</td>
        <td class="loop4">83</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="font-weight-bold">
        <td>Total</td>
        <td class="total1"></td>
        <td class="total2"></td>
        <td class="total3"></td>
        <td class="total4"></td>
      </tr>
     
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

ThankYou!

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- get the number of columns
- loop each column
- `td:nth-child(col)` to get all the TDs for that column
- `.map` to apply your `parseFloat` on each value
- `.get()` to convert jquery collection to an array
- `.reduce()` to sum them all (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers))

Notes:

- `:nth-child` is 1-based, so need to use `cols.length` rather than usual `cols.length - 1`
- need to loop cols from `2` to skip first column, and using 1-based
- added a `totals` class to the totals TR so that it can be excluded from the totals calculation and so we know where to put the final value.  Could also use something like `:not(:last-child)` or similar.
- no need for the `loop1` etc classes, but you may have them for other reasons
- this assumes your columns are to be totalled and you're not totalling "loop1" values that may be in different columns

Giving:

```js
var cols = $("thead th").length;

for (var c = 2; c <= cols; ++c) {

  var total = $("tbody tr:not(.totals) td:nth-child(" + c + ")")
    .map((i, e) => parseFloat($(e).text()))
    .get()
    .reduce((p, c) => p + c, 0)

  $("tbody tr.totals td:nth-child(" + c + ")").text(total);
}
```

```css
.totals > td { font-weight:bold; font-style:italic; border-top:1px solid #CCC; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Store</th>
      <th>Sale</th>
      <th>Revenue</th>
      <th>Payout</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td class="loop1">20</td>
      <td class="loop2">34</td>
      <td class="loop3">65</td>
      <td class="loop4">26</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td class="loop1">76</td>
      <td class="loop2">93</td>
      <td class="loop3">27</td>
      <td class="loop4">83</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="totals">
      <td>Total</td>
      <td class="total1"></td>
      <td class="total2"></td>
      <td class="total3"></td>
      <td class="total4"></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```