# Counting arrays values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have to create a function that receives an array in which every element is a number, or it can be another array with numbers inside, for example :
const array = [1, [2, [3,4]], [5,6], 7];
The function should count all the values and return it
countArray(array); --> should return 28 because (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7)

I tried this

```js
const array = [1, [2, [3,4]], [5,6], 7];

var countArray = function(array) {
  let sum = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
      countArray(array[i])
    }
    sum = sum + array[i]
  }
  return sum
}

console.log(countArray(array));
```

but this does not work, anybody knows why?

Comment: You're calling `countArray`, but you aren't using the result

Comment: You might want to just [`Array.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) first, then [sum normally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers).

Comment: You add `array[i]` to `sum` whether it is itself an array or not.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly you need to do single for incoming nested array. 
 You can use [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method.

```
var nestedArray = [0, 1, 2, [3, 4]]; 
var flatArray = nestedArray.flat(Infinity); // [0,1,2,3,4];
```

[Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) can be used to iterate through the array, 
 adding the current element value to the sum of the previous element values

```
var totalSum = flatArray.reduce(function (accumulator, a) {
  return accumulator + a;
}, 0)
```

So,

```js
    const array = [1, [2, [3,4]], [5,6], 7];
    
    var countArray = function(array) {
    
      var flatArray = array.flat(Infinity);
      var totalSum = flatArray.reduce(function (accumulator, a) {
        return accumulator + a;
      }, 0)
    
      return totalSum;
    }
    
    console.log(countArray(array))
```

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions.  First is simply to modify these lines:

```
        if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
            countArray(array[i])
        }
        sum= sum + array[i]
```

to these:

```
        if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
            sum += countArray(array[i])
        } else {
            sum += array[i]
        }
```

or this:

```
        sum += Array.isArray(array[i]) ? countArray(array[i]) : array[i]
```

Second solution:

```js
const array = [1, [2, [3,4]], [5,6], 7]

countArray = array => array.flat(Infinity).reduce( (a, c) => a + c, 0 );

console.log(countArray(array))
```

The second solution depends on `Array.prototype.flat`, which is fairly (ECMA 2019) recent so support may not be 100%.  There are other options, pretty good list [here](https://www.techiedelight.com/recursively-flatten-nested-array-javascript/)

Answer (score 2):

To spare you the effort of recursion here's a simple trick.

Ordinarily, on its own, [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) will only flatten a series of nested arrays one level deep. If you supply `Infinity` as an argument you can flatten nested arrays `n`-level deep, and then you can [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) over those elements to get the sum.

```js
const array = [1, [2, [3,4]], [5,6, [3, [23, [1, 2, [12]]]]], 7];

function countArray(arr) {
  return arr
    .flat(Infinity)
    .reduce((acc, c) => acc + c, 0);
}

console.log(countArray(array));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use *flat(infinity)* to have all the numbers in the array and then loop through each one to sum them up.

```js
const array = [1, [2, [3, 4]], [5, 6], 7];

const fixedArray = array.flat(Infinity);

let sum = 0;
for (let index = 0; index < fixedArray.length; index++) {
  sum += fixedArray[index];
}

console.log("sum: ", sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing as little as possible about your code, you need add either the `countArray` of the item (if the item is an array) **or** the item itself (if it's not an array) to the sum.

```js
const array = [1, [2, [3,4]], [5,6], 7];

var countArray = function(array) {
  let sum = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
      sum = sum + countArray(array[i])
    } else {
      sum = sum + array[i]
    }
  }
  return sum
}

console.log(countArray(array));
```