# sum a field value in an object array

Tags: javascript, node.js

Grabbing data from a csv file then assigning to an object array, `SmartPostShipments []`. Outputting the "total" number of elements in the array is pretty straightforward by using the `.length` property, but I also need to get the **sum** of each field value in the object array called ['Net Charge Amount']. What is the best way to accomplish this?
I am fine with using `console.log()` for this illustration.

```
const { parse } = require('csv-parse')
const fs = require('fs')
const SmartPostShipments = []

function isSmartpost(shipment) {
    return shipment['Service Type'] === 'SmartPost'
}

fs.createReadStream('test.csv')
    .pipe(parse({
        columns: true
    }))
    
    .on('data', (data) => {
        if (isSmartpost(data)) {
            SmartPostShipments.push(data)
        }

 })
    .on('error', (err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })

 .on ('end', () => {
        
    // This outputs each individual 'net charge amount', but how do I just display the sum 
    // total?
    
    console.log(SmartPostShipments.map((shipment)=> {
            return shipment['Net Charge Amount']
        }))
        
       console.log(`${SmartPostShipments.length} Smartpost shipments.`)
     
    })
```

A couple of the code suggestions look good, but the data is appending instead of summing. Here's a pic of the output:

```
 console.log(SmartPostShipments.map((shipment)=> {
        return shipment['Net Charge Amount']
    }))
            
    const sum = SmartPostShipments.reduce((partialSum, shipment) => partialSum + shipment['Net Charge Amount'], 0)
    console.log(sum)

    const sumSP = SmartPostShipments.reduce((cur, pre)=> {
        return cur+=pre['Net Charge Amount'];
      },0)
      console.log(sumSP)
```

[image]

Comment: Please share your csv file.

Comment: Adding parseInt() did the trick:
return cur += parseInt(pre['Net Charge Amount']);

Total value = 490

Comment: scratch that...using parseFloat(), not parseInt().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const sum = SmartPostShipments.reduce((cur, pre)=> {
  return cur+=pre['Net Charge Amount'];
},0)
console.log(sum)
```

Please try the above. Hope it works.

Comment: He's looking for the sum of a property of the objects, I think it would need to be something like `return cur+=pre['Net Charge Amount'];`

Comment: Thank you, I've just forgot to add that.

Answer (score 4):

This is a variation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers).
Applied to your situation the code would be:

```
const sum = SmartPostShipments.reduce((partialSum, shipment) => partialSum + shipment['Net Charge Amount'], 0)
```