# Google Apps Script - How do I sum elements in a two-dimensional array?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a two dimensional array from a Google spreadsheet.
Logger.log shows it as this:

[ [-4.0], [-1.0], [4.0], [2.0], [1.0], [3.0] ]

All I am trying to do is to sum the 6 elements shown above to return the correct total of 5.0

I have tried using the reduce() method on the array which Logger.log then shows as:

[ -4.0, -1.0, 4.0, 2.0, 1.0, 3.0 ]

But I just cannot figure out how to sum the six elements despite much Googling.
This must be childishly simple - please could someone help this Apps Script novice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the sum of an array of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers)

Comment: I'd use reduce.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the responses.  What worked for me was to flatten the two-dimensional array first, before using reduce().

The two-dimensional array before flattening shows in Logger.log as this:
[ [-4.0], [-1.0], [4.0], [2.0], [1.0], [3.0] ]

and after flattening, it shows like this in Logger.log:
[-4.0], [-1.0], [4.0], [2.0], [1.0], [3.0]

Once flattened, I could then run the reduce() method on the flattened array.

Here's a snippet from the code:

```
var my1dArray = my2dArray.flat();

var total = my1dArray.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
```

If anyone knows a way to total the elements in a two-dimensional array without flattening it first, I would love to hear of it.  Thanks for your patience.