# count each interaction of a reduce

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reduce

I have a list of objects like

```
const usageCosts = {
    224910186407: {
        deviceId: "224910186407",
        currency: "GBP",
        yearlyUsage: 1480.81
    },
    224910464538: {
        deviceId: "224910464538",
        currency: "GBP",
        yearlyUsage: 617.36
    },
    224910464577: {
        deviceId: "224910464577",
        currency: "EUR",
        yearlyUsage: 522.3
    }
}
```

I'm reducing it to sum by currency like

```
 const totalYearlyCost = Object.values(usageCosts).reduce(
      (acc: { [key: string]: any }, stat: any) => {
        if (stat.currency && !acc[stat.currency]) {
          acc[stat.currency] = 0
        }
        return {
          ...acc,
          [stat.currency!]: acc[stat.currency!] + stat.yearlyUsage,
        }
      },
      {},
    )
```

and it returns an object like

```
{
EUR: 522.3
GBP: 2,098.17
}
```

I want to also return the total devices of each currency, something like:

```
{
EUR: 522.3 (1 device)
GBP: 2,098.17 (2 devices)
}
```

tried to add another loop but it's not working as expected

Comment: Your original result is key: string, value: number. By adding `(n device)` you're making the value a string. Is that what you want? Will it interfere with other code used to access the data? Would it be better to have an object like `EUR: { value: 522.3, devices: 1 }`?

Comment: I would really consider @Andy's suggestion if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot easier to do this in 2 parts.

First `reduce` it to an array with the grouped values.

Then loop over (could also a reduce ofc) the object, and [get the sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers) of the array, and add `${array.length} devices` to the string:

```js
const usageCosts = {
    224910186407: {
        deviceId: "224910186407",
        currency: "GBP",
        yearlyUsage: 1480.81
    },
    224910464538: {
        deviceId: "224910464538",
        currency: "GBP",
        yearlyUsage: 617.36
    },
    224910464577: {
        deviceId: "224910464577",
        currency: "EUR",
        yearlyUsage: 522.3
    }
}

let grouped = Object.values(usageCosts).reduce((p, c) => {
    if (!p[c.currency]) p[c.currency] = [];
    p[c.currency].push(c.yearlyUsage);
    return p;
}, {});

for (var key in grouped) {
    grouped[key] = `${grouped[key].reduce((a,b)=>a+b)} (${grouped[key].length}) devices`;
}

console.log(grouped)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution:

```
const result = Object.values(usageCosts).reduce((acc, stat) => {
    if (stat.currency && !acc[stat.currency]) {
        acc[stat.currency] = {
            total: 0,
            devices: 0,
        }
    }

    return {
        ...acc,
        [stat.currency]: {
            total: acc[stat.currency].total + stat.yearlyUsage,
            devices: acc[stat.currency].devices + 1,
        }
    };
}, {});
```

As a result, you will get the following structure:

```
{
  GBP: { total: 2098.17, devices: 2 },
  EUR: { total: 522.3, devices: 1 }
}
```

Comment: This output structure is not the same as OP states in his question.

Comment: @0stone0 it's a far better output. Sometimes OP don't really understand the topic or know what they're after. There's nothing complicated in retrieving the desired concatenation of values at a later time. All it takes is a loop - anyways.

Comment: @0stone0 because it can't be the same. Roko C. Buljan, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

A far better solution would be to get an output like `{"CUR": {yearlyUsage: N, devices: N}, }` - it's more flexible and reusable. Concatenating the values at a later time is also simple:

```js
const usageCosts = {
  3: {deviceId: "3", currency: "GBP", yearlyUsage: 1480.81},
  5: {deviceId: "5", currency: "GBP", yearlyUsage: 617.36},
  7: {deviceId: "7", currency: "EUR", yearlyUsage: 522.3},
};

const byCurrency = Object.values(usageCosts).reduce((ob, {currency, yearlyUsage}) => {
  ob[currency] ??= {yearlyUsage: 0, devices: 0};
  ob[currency].yearlyUsage += yearlyUsage;
  ob[currency].devices += 1;
  return ob;
} , {});


console.log(byCurrency);

// Desired stringified output:
console.log(Object.entries(byCurrency).map(([k,v]) => `${k}: ${v.yearlyUsage} (${v.devices} device${v.devices<2?"":"s"})`).join("\n"))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100dvh !important; top: 0; }
```

The resulting output of `byCurrency` is:

```json
{
  "GBP": {
    "yearlyUsage": 2098.17,
    "devices": 2
  },
  "EUR": {
    "yearlyUsage": 522.3,
    "devices": 1
  }
}
```

and the second custom output (concatenated values):

```
GBP: 2098.17 (2 devices)
EUR: 522.3 (1 device)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. Access the values of the object and reduce by the `currency` and keep track of a `count` and `total`
2. Access the entries of the `Map`, sort by the key (`currency`), and reduce into an object where the key is the `currency` and the value is the formatted `count` and `total`

```js
const usageCosts = {
  224910186407: { deviceId: "224910186407", currency: "GBP", yearlyUsage: 1480.81 },
  224910464538: { deviceId: "224910464538", currency: "GBP", yearlyUsage:  617.36 },
  224910464577: { deviceId: "224910464577", currency: "EUR", yearlyUsage:   522.3 }
};

const summary =
  // Part 1
  Array.from(Object.values(usageCosts)
    .reduce((acc, { currency, yearlyUsage }) => 
      (({ count = 0, total = 0 }) =>
        acc.set(currency, { count: count + 1, total: total + yearlyUsage }))
      (acc.get(currency) ?? {}), new Map)
    .entries())
  // Part 2
  .sort(([a], [b]) => a.localeCompare(b)) // Sort keys
  .reduce((acc, [currency, { count, total }]) => Object.assign(acc, {
    [currency]: `${total} (${count} device${count > 1 ? 's' : ''})`
  }), {});

console.log(summary);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important }
```