# How to use filter, map, and reduce in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, filter, functional-programming, reduce

This is how I am accustomed to `filter`, `map`, and `reduce` working in Python 2:

```
>>> def f(x):
        return x % 2 != 0 and x % 3 != 0
>>> filter(f, range(2, 25))
[5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23]

>>> def cube(x):
        return x*x*x
>>> map(cube, range(1, 11))
[1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729, 1000]

>>> def add(x,y):
        return x+y
>>> reduce(add, range(1, 11))
55
```

However, all of these seem to break in Python 3:

```
>>> filter(f, range(2, 25))
<filter object at 0x0000000002C14908>

>>> map(cube, range(1, 11))
<map object at 0x0000000002C82B70>

>>> reduce(add, range(1, 11))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    reduce(add, range(1, 11))
NameError: name 'reduce' is not defined
```

Why are the results different? How can I get Python 3 code to work like the Python 2 code did?

---

<sub>See also: [What is the problem with reduce()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181543) for specific motivation for the change to put `reduce` into a standard library module rather than leaving it as a builtin.</sub>

<sub>See [Getting a map() to return a list in Python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303347) for more specific answers about `map`.</sub>

Comment: In short, list is not the only datatype. If you want a list, say you want a list. But in most cases, you want something else anyway.

Answer (score 385, accepted):

You can read about the changes in [What's New In Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html). You should read it thoroughly when you move from 2.x to 3.x since a lot has been changed.

The whole answer here are quotes from the documentation.

**[Views And Iterators Instead Of Lists](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists)**

> Some well-known APIs no longer return lists:
>
> - [...]
> - [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#map) and [`filter()`](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#filter) return iterators. If you really need a list, a quick fix is e.g. `list(map(...))`, but a better fix is often to use a list comprehension (especially when the original code uses lambda), or rewriting the code so it doesn’t need a list at all. Particularly tricky is `map()` invoked for the side effects of the function; the correct transformation is to use a regular `for` loop (since creating a list would just be wasteful).
> - [...]

**[Builtins](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins)**

> - [...]
> - Removed `reduce()`. Use [`functools.reduce()`](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) if you really need it; however, 99 percent of the time an explicit `for` loop is more readable.
> - [...]

Comment: Adding `list(map(...) ` everywhere  ..  how in the world is that helping readability..  `python` can't seem to handle progressive / streaming application of functional combinators. Other languages I can chain a dozen operations against a collection in a row and it's readable. Here? what do you want - a dozen way nested `in` ??

Comment: If you're working in an imperative context, then a for-loop is probably the more readable option.  But there are good reasons to prefer a functional context--and breaking from that to go back to procedural can be pretty darn ugly.

Comment: @javadba Are you sure in a "streaming application" you need to add the `list` call at all? I thought the meaning of "streaming" is "no list is created at all; process each element of the input fully before moving on to the next".

Comment: @MatrixManAtYrService If you are sure the python 2 behavior is what you need, you can always just redefine `map`.

Comment: I still cant grasp how a readability argument leads to such a change. If it was for performance reasons I might understand...

Comment: readability is one thing, but it makes (list, dict, ...)comprehensions unusable. Can't put an ordinary for loop in the middle of a list comprehension, now can I.. ugh.

Comment: A "quick fix" (read: hack) is to use list(map...) but notice the "better fix" is to use a list comprehension instead - like [Foo(x) for x in mylist]. This doesn't lead to adding list() everywhere and longer term may be better. (@javadba FYI)

Comment: @dmonopoly  I specifically mentioned applying a dozen transformations and that I do not want to have a 12 way nested list comprehension - which is the only option in standard python afaik

Answer (score 102):

The functionality of `map` and `filter` was intentionally changed to return iterators, and reduce was removed from being a built-in and placed in `functools.reduce`.

So, for `filter` and `map`, you can wrap them with `list()` to see the results like you did before.

```
>>> def f(x): return x % 2 != 0 and x % 3 != 0
...
>>> list(filter(f, range(2, 25)))
[5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23]
>>> def cube(x): return x*x*x
...
>>> list(map(cube, range(1, 11)))
[1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729, 1000]
>>> import functools
>>> def add(x,y): return x+y
...
>>> functools.reduce(add, range(1, 11))
55
>>>
```

The recommendation now is that you replace your usage of map and filter with generators expressions or list comprehensions.  Example:

```
>>> def f(x): return x % 2 != 0 and x % 3 != 0
...
>>> [i for i in range(2, 25) if f(i)]
[5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23]
>>> def cube(x): return x*x*x
...
>>> [cube(i) for i in range(1, 11)]
[1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729, 1000]
>>>
```

They say that for loops are 99 percent of the time easier to read than reduce, but I'd just stick with `functools.reduce`.

**Edit**: The 99 percent figure is pulled directly from the [What’s New In Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html) page authored by Guido van Rossum.

Comment: You do not need to create extra functions in list comprehensions. Just use `[i*i*i for i in range(1,11)]`

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  I kept the function in the list comprehension examples to keep it looking similar to the filter/map examples.

Comment: i**3 is also equivalent of i\*i\*i

Comment: @Breezer actually `i**3` will call `i.__pow__(3)` and `i*i*i` `i.__mul__(i).__mul__(i)` (or something like that). With ints it doesn't matter but with numpy numbers/custom classes it might even produce different results.

Comment: @JoshuaD.Boyd But which is faster? A `map` or `generator`?

Comment: I  have noticed that whenever we hear that "Guido made decision X" that *pain* is a likely outcome.  This is a great example: `list(list(list(.. )))` to do what was *already* verbose in python.

Answer (score 12):

As an addendum to the other answers, this sounds like a fine use-case for a context manager that will re-map the names of these functions to ones which return a list and introduce `reduce` in the global namespace.

A quick implementation might look like this:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager    

@contextmanager
def noiters(*funcs):
    if not funcs: 
        funcs = [map, filter, zip] # etc
    from functools import reduce
    globals()[reduce.__name__] = reduce
    for func in funcs:
        globals()[func.__name__] = lambda *ar, func = func, **kwar: list(func(*ar, **kwar))
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        del globals()[reduce.__name__]
        for func in funcs: globals()[func.__name__] = func
```

With a usage that looks like this:

```
with noiters(map):
    from operator import add
    print(reduce(add, range(1, 20)))
    print(map(int, ['1', '2']))
```

Which prints:

```
190
[1, 2]
```

Just my 2 cents :-)

Comment: `python` as a language is a mess  - but it has v good to excellent libraries: `numpy`, `pandas`, `statsmodels` and friends..   I had been buliding  convenience libraries like you show here to reduce the pain of the native language - but have lost the energy and try not to stray far from a `data.frame` / `datatable`, or `xarray`.  But kudos for trying..

Answer (score 10):

Since the `reduce` method has been removed from the built in function from Python3, don't forget to import the `functools` in your code. Please look at the code snippet below.

```
import functools
my_list = [10,15,20,25,35]
sum_numbers = functools.reduce(lambda x ,y : x+y , my_list)
print(sum_numbers)
```

Answer (score 5):

One of the advantages of map, filter and reduce is how legible they become when you "chain" them together to do something complex. However, the built-in syntax isn't legible and is all "backwards". So, I suggest using the `PyFunctional` package (https://pypi.org/project/PyFunctional/). 
**Here's a comparison of the two:**

```
flight_destinations_dict = {'NY': {'London', 'Rome'}, 'Berlin': {'NY'}}
```

**PyFunctional version**

Very legible syntax. You can say:

> "I have a sequence of flight destinations.  Out of which I want to get
>   the dict key if city is in the dict values.  Finally, filter out the
>   empty lists I created in the process."

```
from functional import seq  # PyFunctional package to allow easier syntax

def find_return_flights_PYFUNCTIONAL_SYNTAX(city, flight_destinations_dict):
    return seq(flight_destinations_dict.items()) \
        .map(lambda x: x[0] if city in x[1] else []) \
        .filter(lambda x: x != []) \
```

**Default Python version**

It's all backwards. You need to say:

> "OK, so, there's a list.  I want to filter empty lists out of it.  Why?
>   Because I first got the dict key if the city was in the dict values. 
>   Oh, the list I'm doing this to is flight_destinations_dict."

```
def find_return_flights_DEFAULT_SYNTAX(city, flight_destinations_dict):
    return list(
        filter(lambda x: x != [],
               map(lambda x: x[0] if city in x[1] else [], flight_destinations_dict.items())
               )
    )
```

Comment: Would it also work to try something like:

```python
def find_return_flights(city):
    return [key for key, val in flight_destinations_dict.items() if city in val]
```

Comment: It probably would, but that wouldn't be strictly speaking functional programming.

Answer (score 1):

```
from functools import reduce

def f(x):
    return x % 2 != 0 and x % 3 != 0

print(*filter(f, range(2, 25)))
#[5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23]

def cube(x):
    return x**3
print(*map(cube, range(1, 11)))
#[1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729, 1000]

def add(x,y):
    return x+y

reduce(add, range(1, 11))
#55
```

It works as is.  To get the output of map use * or list

Answer (score 0):

Here are the examples of Filter, map and reduce functions.

> > > numbers = [10,11,12,22,34,43,54,34,67,87,88,98,99,87,44,66]

//Filter

> > > oddNumbers = list(filter(lambda x: x%2 != 0, numbers))
> > >
> > > print(oddNumbers)

//Map

> > > multiplyOf2 = list(map(lambda x: x*2, numbers))
> > >
> > > print(multiplyOf2)

//Reduce

The reduce function, since it is not commonly used, was removed from the built-in functions in Python 3. It is still available in the functools module, so you can do:

> > > from functools import reduce
> > >
> > > sumOfNumbers = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, numbers)
> > >
> > > print(sumOfNumbers)