# How to remove all the punctuation in a string? (Python)

Tags: python

For example:

```
asking="hello! what's your name?"
```

Can I just do this?

```
asking.strip("!'?")
```

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A really simple implementation is:

```
out = "".join(c for c in asking if c not in ('!','.',':'))
```

and keep adding any other types of punctuation.

A more efficient way would be

```
import string
stringIn = "string.with.punctuation!"
out = stringIn.translate(stringIn.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation)
```

Edit: There is some more discussion on efficiency and other implementations here:
[Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: `strip()` won't work. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip

Comment: @BrendenBrown You are indeed correct. Half a year without looking at python and what do you know. Shameful edit ensuing.

Comment: For deleting you can simplify the last line to `out = stringIn.translate(None, string.punctuation)` (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)

Comment: For Python 3, https://stackoverflow.com/a/34294398/343215

Answer (score 15):

```
import string

asking = "".join(l for l in asking if l not in string.punctuation)
```

filter with [`string.punctuation`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.punctuation).

Answer (score 0):

This works, but there might be better solutions.

```
asking="hello! what's your name?"
asking = ''.join([c for c in asking if c not in ('!', '?')])
print asking
```

Comment: you don't need the inner list in this scenario, and this will return `'hellowhat'syourname'`.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid You're right inner list is not needed but the output is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Strip won't work. It only removes leading and trailing instances, not everything in between: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip

Having fun with filter:

```
import string
asking = "hello! what's your name?"
predicate = lambda x:x not in string.punctuation
filter(predicate, asking)
```

Comment: .It is important to wrap `list()` around the entire `filter()` function if you're using Python 3.x, as many built-in functions no longer return `lists` but special `iterable` objects.  Also, you seem to have overlooked putting `input` (or `raw_input` for Python 2.x) around the string in the second line, and you should have put something like `asking = ...` for the final line.

Comment: Looks like this approach is discouraged in 3.x: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638898/how-to-use-filter-map-and-reduce-in-python-3-3-0

Comment: `filter` is ugly and slow when you have to use a `lambda` with it, unfortunately your alternative is `''.join(ifilterfalse(partial(contains, punctuation), asking))`