# Remove punctuations in a string

Tags: python, string, split

I have a list of strings that I would love to change to lower cases and remove punctuations. I am able to change them to lower cases but fail to remove punctuations. Example of the string:

```
s = 'He is the best doctor. I highly recommend him."
```

With

```
slower = s.lower().split(" ")
```

I obtain

```
['he', 'is', 'the', 'best', 'doctor.', 'i', 'like', 'him.']
```

This is good, but I still would like to detach punctuations from the words.

What's the easy way to do this? Thank you!!

Comment: This should be useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python

Comment: Or this http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/110419/removing-punctuation-and-lowercasing-a-string

Comment: This is also viable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050952/how-to-remove-all-the-punctuation-in-a-string-python

Comment: @desimusxvii, codereview is for working code

Comment: Thank you very much for the inputs!

Comment: Easy quick way to do it: `s.lower().replace('.','').split(' ')`

Comment: Thank you @Tsangares, this is really cool.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham While you are correct that Code Review is for working code, we require the code to be fully doing what the OP intended and not requesting changes in the functionality.

Comment: @Hosch250, that was the point I thought I was making.

Comment: OK, thanks for knowing CR's scope.